# Return Inherited Generics as Base Generic

Tags: vb.net, generics, inheritance

I have `BaseAbstractClass(of T as WebControl)` (VB Generics) which inherits `WebControl`.

`BaseAbstractClass` is inherited by `ConcreteWrapper1`, `ConcreteWrapper2`, and lastly, to shake things up a bit, `ConcreteWrapper4`.  Each of these would inherit `BaseAbstractClass` using a different class inherited from `WebControl`.

What I would like to do is have factory that returns a `ConcreteWrapper` as a `BaseAbstractClass(of WebControl)`.  But whenever I try to return a new instance of a `ConcreteWrapper` I get a compile time conversion error.

[Edit:  Code Added]

BaseAbstractClass

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseAbstractClass(Of T As WebControl)
    Inherits WebControl

    Protected _item As T

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        _item.RenderControl(writer)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The other ConcreteWrappers look like this except with different CustomControl

```
Public Class ConcreteWrapper1
    Inherits BaseAbstractClass(Of CustomControlInheritedFromWebControl1)

    Public Sub New(ByVal control As CustomControlInheritedFromWebControl1)
        MyBase._item = control
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class CustomControlInheritedFromWebControl1
    Inherits WebControl

    //not the correct comment markers but the coloring works better
    //do stuff here... Implm not important.

End Class
```

My Factory

```
Public Class WebControlFactory

    Public Shared Function GetWebControl() As BaseAbstractClass(Of WebControl)

        Return New ConcreteWrapper1(New CustomControlInheritedFromWebControl1())

    End Function

End Class
```

[/Edit]

Could I get an explanation of what's going on and why that won't work (and possibly, a solution)?

Thanks!

Comment: Posting a code snippet would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConcreteWrapper1` does not inherit from `BaseAbstractClass(of WebControl)`, instead it inherits from `BaseAbstractClass(of T)`

BAC(of WebControl) is not interchangable with BAC(of T).

If you must use inheritence, you need two levels of abstraction.

```
WebControl
  BAC inherits WebControl
    BAC(of T) inherits BAC
      Wrapper1 inherits BAC(of int)
      Wrapper2 inherits BAC(of string)
      Wrapper3 inherits BAC(of Foo)
      Wrapper4 inherits BAC(of Bar)
```

Then you may return all instances of your Wrappers as BAC.

The reason is phrased well by [Zooba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557/in-c-why-cant-a-liststring-object-be-stored-in-a-listobject-variable#7168):

> You cannot cast between generic types with different type parameters. Specialized generic types don't form part of the same inheritance tree and so are unrelated types.

Comment: Aaah.  Awesome.  I get why that works, however, I don't entirely understand why BAC(of WebControl) and BAC(of T as WebControl) are not compatible. T is required to be a WebControl.