# Casting from IEnumerable<Object> to IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, covariance, contravariance

Recently I found a very surprising behavior in c#.
I had a method which takes `IEnumerable<Object>` as a parameter and i was passing
`IEnumerable<string>` but it's not possible.
While in c# everything can be upcast to Object than why this is not possible?
It's totally confusing for me.
Please someone clear me on this issue.

Comment: How is it not possible? Is it throwing an ArgumentException? Besides, what's the point of using a generic IEnumerable if you're going to declare it as an Object?

Comment: Same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557/in-c-why-cant-a-liststring-object-be-stored-in-a-listobject-variable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The technical term for this is that generics are invariant in C# 3.0 and earlier. From C#4.0 onward, the cast works.

What invariant means is that there is no relationship between two generic types just because their generic type *parameters* are related (i.e. are sub- or supertypes of each other).

In your example, there is no typing relationship between an `IEnumerable<object>` and an `IEnumerable<string>`, just because string is a subtype of object. They're just considered two completely unrelated types, like a string and an int (they still both are subtypes of object, but everything is)

There are a few workarounds and exceptions for this issue you've run into.

First, you can cast each string individually to object, if you're using .NET 3.0 you can do that using the `Cast<T>()` extension method. Otherwise, you can use a foreach and put the result into a new variable of the static type you want.

Second, arrays are an exception for reference type, i.e. passing in a string[] type to a method acccepting object[] types should work.

Comment: Just to update this older answer, covariance and contravariance are now supported in C#, and this is now a valid cast.

Answer (score 8):

As others have pointed out, generics types are invariant. `IEnumerable<T>` could be co-variant but C# doesn't currently support specifying variants. C# 4.0 is expected to support variants so this might be supported in the future.

To work around this now you can using a the LINQ extension method `Cast<object>()`. Assuming you have a method called `Foo` that takes an `IEnumerable<object>>`. You can call it like this,

```
Foo(stringEnumerable.Cast<object>());
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to pass `IEnumerable<string>` to function requiring `IEnumerable<object>` is through converting function like this:

```
public IEnumerable<object> convert<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
    foreach (T o in enumerable)
        yield return o;
    }
```

When C# 4 comes out, this won't be neccessary, because it will support covariance and contravariance.

Comment: This is exactly what Cast<> is for :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
IEnumerable<T>
```

if you want to pass in different types, then you can query T to find out what type it is.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to think about this is to ask yourself "What would happen if you could do this?". Take the following example:

```
IEnumerable<String> strings=...;
IEnumerable<Object> objects = strings; // assume this were legal

objects.Add(new Integer(5)); // what the...
```

We just added an integer to a list of strings. The compiler does this to preserve type safety.

Comment: IEnumerable<T> doesn't have an Add method though... And in C# 4.0 you will actually be able to perform this cast as the declaration will change to IEnumerable<out T> allowing it to be (safely) contravariant.

Comment: Well substitute any generic class that does have an Add method like List then

Comment: -1: `IEnumerable<T>` becomes `IEnumerable<out T>` in .NET 4 specifically because your argument makes sense for a container but *not* for an enumeration.