# Casting Problem within generic types but the same types

Tags: c#, generics

**The interface:**
interface IPlay`<`T`>` { }

**Classes:**
class Mp3Player : IPlay`<`int`>` { }
class OggPlayer : IPlay`<`double`>` { }
class DummyPlayer : IPlay`<`object`>` { }

**Trying to use :** 
1. IPlay`<`object`>` player = new Mp3Player ();
2. IPlay`<`int`>` player2 = new OggPlayer ();

A Big why 1 and 2. usages can not cast? 
int to object, or, int to double. It's possible in nongeneric cases. Is there any other method?

Comment: It's not an *exact* duplicate, but I'm voting to close because this question is very close to all the co/contravariance questions out there. Check out this one for some discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557/in-c-why-cant-a-liststring-object-be-stored-in-a-listobject-variable

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to perform invalid casts. The Mp3Player is not an IPlay<object>, it is an IPlay<int>. Your OggPlayer is an IPlay<double>, not an IPlay<int>. You can't cast an IPlay<int> to an IPlay<object> or an IPlay<double> to an IPlay<int> like that. They don't inherit from each other, and because they are generic, they are distinct types strongly differentiated from each other.

In C# 4.0 such implicit casts might, and I stress MIGHT, be possible, due to the improved co/contra variance it will have. But generally speaking, such implicit casts across distinct type boundaries are not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine:

```
interface IPlay<T>
{
    T GetSomething();
    DoSomething(T value);
}
```

So, when using:

```
IPlay<object> player = new Mp3Player();
```

Then `GetSomething()` may be type safe, but how about `DoSomething(object value)`? ... That call cannot guarantee the logic will work on an object, since the player expects ints.

Note that .NET 4 has a mechanism to indicate the variance of an interface, so that you can mark the interface as only using `T` as return values, in which case at least your first assignment will work.

Note however that regardless, the second (`IPlay<int> player2`) will not work, because there is no inheritance relationship between `double` and `int`. Being able to cast values implicitly is not the same thing as inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking to do is called [covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) and this feature will be supported in C# 4 on interface types.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a good talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL16/) by Anders Hejlsberg from PDC where he describes how co/contravariance will work in C# 4.0 (among other things).

Answer (score 0):

There's a common misconception that `IPlay<T>` generates a common ancestor, which would be `IPlay<object>`.  This might be valuable, but it is not true.

You must generate and name the common ancestor yourself:

```
interface IPlay {}
interface IPlay<T> : IPlay {}
```