# Inheritance in C# - simple question

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, covariance

> #### Duplicate
>
> [In C#, why can’t a List object be stored in a List variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557/in-c-why-cant-a-liststring-object-be-stored-in-a-listobject-variable)

Here is my code:

```
public class Base
    {
        protected BindingList<SampleBase> m_samples;

        public Base() { }
    }

    public class Derived : Base
    {
        public Derived()
        {
            m_samples = new BindingList<SampleDerived>();
        }
    }
```

SampleDerived is derived from SampleBase

According to the inheritance logic, I should be able to do this. However, it doesn't compile - the error says that SampleBase can not be be implicitly converted to SampleDerived type. What gives?

I am using c# 2.0

Comment: Please look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557/in-c-why-cant-a-liststring-object-be-stored-in-a-listobject-variable

Comment: @gnomixa: "According to the inheritance logic" => there is no inheritance logic; two different type parameterizations are not the same types (the members they effectively define are different), although covariance suggest that they have something in common (the relationship between the type-parameter arguments SampleBase and SampleDerived). C# 4.0 will support covariance.

Comment: Can someone share experiences on how to achieve what I want? Surely, it has been done before. All I see is theory and pointing out what's wrong. Can someone offer a WORKING solution that would achieve my objective? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use covariance, which is not supported by C# 3.0 and earlier (but will be in C# 4.0). You can still add objects of type `SampleDerived` into `m_samples`, but the list's generic type will need to be `SampleBase`.

**Edit:** So Pavel is right, C# 4.0 doesn't actually help with this. It would if `m_sample` were defined as `IBindingList<SampleBase>` using (fictional) covariant interface `IBindingList<out T>`.

Comment: This particular scenario won't be helped by covariance support in C# 4.0. For one thing, C# 4.0 only supports variance for interfaces, not for classes. For another (and more importantly), `BindingList<T>` (and any other mutable collection class) is not covariant.

Comment: @Pavel Minaev: "C# 4.0 only supports variance for interfaces[.]" And delegates.

Comment: you may find Eric Lippert's articles on covariance and contravariance interesting. Part 1 - http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I can understand why you would think that but generics don't work that way.  :(

```
BindingList<SampleDerived> does not actually derive from BindingList<SampleBase>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `BindingList<SampleDerived>` is not a `BindingList<SampleBase>` -- you can add a `SampleBase` to the latter, but not to the former.

Answer (score 0):

Generics cannot be casted.

You can cast `List<MyClass>` to `IList<MyClass>` or even `IList`, but this would be illegal:

```
List<Object> = new List<MyClass>();
```

Comment: Hah They stripped your angle brackets too

Comment: C# doesn't have templates. Generics aren't templates.

Comment: Subtle difference, but thanks for the info. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[This type of generic variance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233054(VS.100).aspx) is not supported in C#2 or 3.  <strike>It will be supported in C#4.</strike> (See comment.)  Eric Lippert has a [series of blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx) on this subject that goes into enough detail to kill any unwary developer. :)

Comment: This particular scenario won't be helped by covariance support in C# 4.0. For one thing, C# 4.0 only supports variance for interfaces, not for classes. For another (and more importantly), BindingList<T> (and any other mutable collection class) is not covariant.

Comment: There's enough pure concentrated variance in there to turn you all into hermit crabs, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you must simply create the list instance in your base class, and freely use it in derived.

```
public class Base
{
    protected BindingList<SampleBase> m_samples = new BindingList<Derived>();

    public Base() { }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public FwdRunData()
    {
        m_samples.Add(new Derived>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Except that I am going to have several classes that are derived from SampleBase....so my whole point was that I won't have to declare and create m_samples in each class that has been derived from Base.

Answer (score 0):

The people pointing you to Eric Lippert's excellent posts on variance are right, but here's a short example showing what would go wrong.  I've just added a new method to the base class and I'm using another derived sample class.  What would happen when the `BreakDerived` method is called on an instance of your original `Derived` class?  You can't add an instance of `SampleDerived2` to the `BindingList<SampledDerived>`.

```
public class Base {
    protected BindingList<SampleBase> m_samples;
    public Base() { }
    public BreakDerived() { m_samples.Add(new SampleDerived2()); }    
}

public class Derived : Base {
    public Derived() { m_samples = new BindingList<SampledDerived>(); }
}
```