# Why can't I cast EntityCollection<TEntity> to ICollection<Object>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

If I try to cast an object of type `EntityCollection<MyNamespace.Models.MyEntityClass>` to `ICollection<Object>` I get an `InvalidCastException`.

Okay, according to the docs, `EntityCollection<TEntity>` implements `ICollection<T>`, and `MyNamespace.Models.MyEntityClass` must descend from `Object`, right? So why on earth does this fail?

FWIW, I'm trying to do this in a method that generally can add and remove items from what might be an `EntityCollection` or some other `IList` or `ISet`. I need to preserve the change tracking behavior of EntityCollection, because the object is to eventually be able to commit the changes if it's an EC.

### Edit

Okay, here's some more specifics of what I'm doing. I'm deserializing JSON, and the target object can have properties that are collections--maybe they're `EntityCollection`s, maybe not. For the sake of simplicity, lets say the members of the collection are always subclasses of `EntityObject`, whether it's an `EntityCollection` or not (if I understand the responses so far, I'd have no better luck casting to `ICollection<EntityObject>` than to `ICollection<Object>`…right?). This is the part where I run into trouble…

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in hasManys)
{
    // This is where I get the InvalidCastException...
    ICollection<Object> oldHms = (ICollection<Object>)prop.GetValue(parentObj, null);

    JEnumerable<JToken> hmIds = links[FormatPropName(prop.Name)].Children();
    if (hmIds.Count() == 0)
    {
        // No members! Clear it out!
        oldHms.Clear();
        continue; // breaking early!
    }

    relType = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    // Get back the actual entities we'll need to put into the relationship...
    List<EntityObject> newHms = new List<EntityObject>();
    foreach (JToken jt in hmIds)
    {
        // ...populate newHms with existing EntityObjects from the context...
    }

        // first, delete any missing...
        /* Got to use ToList() to make a copy, because otherwise missings is 
         * still connected to the oldHms collection (It's an ObjectQuery)
         * and you can't modify oldHms while enumerating missings. 
         */
        // This cast will fail too, right? Though it's more easily fixable:
        IEnumerable<EntityObject> missings = ((ICollection<EntityObject>)oldHms).Except(newHms).ToList();
        foreach (EntityObject missing in missings)
        {
            oldHms.Remove(missing); // One of my mutable collection operations
        }

        // add new ones
        foreach (EntityObject child in newHms)
        {
            if (!oldHms.Contains(child)) // Skip if already in there
            {
                oldHms.Add(child); // another mutable collection operation
            }
        }

    }

}
```

That's a bit simplified, I have special cases for Arrays (implement ICollection, but aren't generics) and other stuff that I took out. Point is, I need to operate `Clear`, `Add`, and `Remove` on the `EntityCollection` itself--if that's what it is. Maybe there's another way to do this type of synchronization that I'm missing?

Comment: This link might help you:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360184/c-sharp-casting-generic-type][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360184/c-sharp-casting-generic-type

Comment: @Onur Hmm..interesting…but I am on .Net 4.0 and these are reference types…?

Comment: Fundamentally, if `Y` descends from `X`, `Generic<Y>` is **not** a subtype of `Generic<X>`, because you would violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). I.e. pretty much the definition of the subtyping relationship in OO languages. What you're doing fails because it does not in fact make any sense for it to succeed.

Comment: Also: can't you make the method generic over the type of the item? E.g.: `void AddEntity<T>(ICollection<T> items) { … }`

Comment: @millimoose: This is only true if you have _both_ get and set methods. Otherwise covariance or contravariance will be fine.

Comment: @Onur – There are no "write-only" collection interfaces in the BCL, and the OP mentions he wants to add items.

Comment: That's right. But your statement sounded more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read-write collections cannot be variant.

Take this example:

```
List<MyClass> list1 = new List<MyClass>();

// assume this would work
ICollection<object> list2 = list1;

list2.Add(new object()); // ooops. We added an object to List<MyClass>!
```

In principal this kind of casting is only possible for "read-only" interfaces (allowing covariance) or for "write-only" interfaces (allowing contravariance).

One "solution" would involve a wrapper class like this:

```
public class Wrapper<T> : ICollection<object>
{
    private readonly ICollection<T> collection;
    public Wrapper(ICollection<T> collection)
    {
        this.collection = collection;
    }


    public void Add(object item)
    {
        // maybe check if T is of the desired type
        collection.Add((T)item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        collection.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(object item)
    {
        // maybe check if T is of the desired type
        return collection.Contains((T)item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(object[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        // maybe check if T is of the desired type
        collection.CopyTo(array.Cast<T>().ToArray(), arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return collection.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return collection.IsReadOnly; }
    }

    public bool Remove(object item)
    {
        // maybe check if T is of the desired type
        return collection.Remove((T)item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<object> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return collection;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return collection.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Instead of

```
 EntityCollection<MyNamespace.Models.MyEntityClass> collection = ...;
 ICollection<Object> generic = collection ;
```

you would have to write:

```
 EntityCollection<MyNamespace.Models.MyEntityClass> collection = ...;
 ICollection<Object> generic = new Wrapper(collection);
```

And could adjust the wrapper class at the points marked by comments how to deal with type problems.

Comment: Ahhhh…quite right, I see why this would be bad. Still, I could live with that last line throwing a runtime error. We're in runtime at this point anyway, because the compiler can't see what I've got before I try to cast it (I am using `PropertyInfo.GetValue`). But ugh…then is there no way to write the generalized code I'm trying to? Without using `GetMethod` or something of that nature? I want to use `Clear`, `Add`, and `Remove` on the whatever-collection.

Comment: @S'pht'Kr "Still, I could live with that last line throwing a runtime error." – the compiler can't. The only appropriate runtime error is a class cast exception, but the compiler can't really insert a cast since it doesn't know what type it's casting to. (You *could* have it insert some code to dynamically determine this but that would probably mean all type errors would be moved to runtime.) If you want a runtime error you'll have to make it explicit by casting to *something*. So if you make your method `AddItem<T>(ICollection<T> items)`, you can do `items.Add((T) value)`

Answer (score 1):

Since `ICollection<T>` hasn't variance, `ICollection<MyEntityClass>` and `ICollection<object>` are different types, unrelated to each other.

> I'm trying to do this in a method that generally can add and remove
>   items from what might be an EntityCollection or some other IList or
>   ISet

So, why don't you work with `IList`? Looks like you don't care about real type of items in this method.

Comment: Hmm… work with IList how so? Okay, so I can cast it to `IEnumerable<Object>`, but if I call `.ToList()` on that, it will be a copy--if I add and remove things, the `EntityCollection` will not know about it.

Comment: @S'pht'Kr: may be, you'll post the code of your method?

Comment: Done, perhaps that clarifies things a bit?