# C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>

Tags: c#, covariance

Look at the following example (partially taken from [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx)):

```
class Animal { }
class Giraffe : Animal { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Array assignment works, but...
    Animal[] animals = new Giraffe[10]; 

    // implicit...
    List<Animal> animalsList = new List<Giraffe>();

    // ...and explicit casting fails
    List<Animal> animalsList2 = (List<Animal>) new List<Giraffe>();
}
```

Is this a covariance problem? Will this be supported in the future C# release and are there any clever workarounds (using only .NET 2.0)?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Well this certainly won't be supported in C# 4. There's a fundamental problem:

```
List<Giraffe> giraffes = new List<Giraffe>();
giraffes.Add(new Giraffe());
List<Animal> animals = giraffes;
animals.Add(new Lion()); // Aargh!
```

Keep giraffes safe: just say no to unsafe variance.

The array version works because arrays *do* support reference type variance, with *runtime* checking. The point of generics is to provide *compile-time* type safety.

In C# 4 there will be support for *safe* generic variance, but only for interfaces and delegates. So you'll be able to do:

```
Func<string> stringFactory = () => "always return this string";
Func<object> objectFactory = stringFactory; // Safe, allowed in C# 4
```

`Func<out T>` is *covariant* in `T` because `T` is only used in an output position. Compare that with `Action<in T>` which is contravariant in `T` because `T` is only used in an input position there, making this safe:

```
Action<object> objectAction = x => Console.WriteLine(x.GetHashCode());
Action<string> stringAction = objectAction; // Safe, allowed in C# 4
```

`IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant as well, making this correct in C# 4, as pointed out by others:

```
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = new List<Giraffe>();
// Can't add a Lion to animals, as `IEnumerable<out T>` is a read-only interface.
```

In terms of working around this in your situation in C# 2, do you need to maintain *one* list, or would you be happy creating a new list? If that's acceptable, `List<T>.ConvertAll` is your friend.

Comment: +1 just to add to Jon's answer (not that he needs any help ), following the `Func<string>` to `Func<object>` example and the fact that `T` is contravariant in `Action`. The following `Action<object> = Action<string>` would not work in C# 4.

Comment: Thanks for also pointing out the type safety problem. That's really helpful.

Comment: What is wrong with `animals.Add(new Lion()); // Aargh!`? If you can cast a `Lion` and use it as an `Animal`, and if you are using all of the elements in `animals` as `Animal`s, then what is the problem?

Comment: @Jeff: Because `animals` *actually* refers to a `List<Giraffe>`. So you'd end up with a `Lion` reference in a `List<Giraffe>`, which is bad...

Comment: Worth mentioning that a better fit for List<T> might be IReadOnlyList<out T> which is also safely covariant, being immutable.

Comment: @x0n: I'm happy for you to mention that, but I'm not going to update all my old answer with types introduced later on.

Comment: @JonSkeet I realise that :) That's why it wasn't put forward as a correction. I realized that when I saw the date of your original answer :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Having a `Lion` reference in a `List<Giraffe>` *casted* as a `List<Animal>` does not seem bad to me (logically speaking. Could be technically problematic for the .NET runtime though)

Comment: @AlexandreDaubricourt: But some other piece of code could refer to the same object as a `List<Giraffe>` (as in my example). So you'd get an error when that tried to do anything, but that could be much, much later. Better to spot the problem early, IMO.

Answer (score 17):

It will work in C#4 for `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can do:

```
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = new List<Giraffe>();
```

However `List<T>` is not a covarient projection, so you cannot assign lists as you have done above since you could do this:

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Giraffe>();
animals.Add(new Monkey());
```

Which is clearly not valid.

Answer (score 9):

In terms of `List<T>`, I'm afraid you're out of luck. However, .NET 4.0/C# 4.0 adds support for covariant/contravariant interfaces. Specifically, `IEnumerable<T>` is now defined as [`IEnumerable<out T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28VS.100%29.aspx), which means that the type parameter is now *covariant*.

This means you can do something like this in C# 4.0...

```
// implicit casting
IEnumerable<Animal> animalsList = new List<Giraffe>();

// explicit casting
IEnumerable<Animal> animalsList2 = (IEnumerable<Animal>) new List<Giraffe>();
```

Note: Array types have also been covariant (at least since .NET 1.1).

I think it's a shame that variance support wasn't added for `IList<T>` and other similar generic interfaces (or generic classes even), but oh well, at least we have something.

Comment: You can't make IList<T> covariant safely with declaration-side variance annotations.

Answer (score 4):

Covariance/contravariance can't be supported on mutable collections as others have mentioned because it's impossible to guarantee type safety both ways at compile time; however, it is possible to do a quick one-way conversion in C# 3.5, if that is what you're looking for:

```
List<Giraffe> giraffes = new List<Giraffe>();
List<Animal> animals = giraffes.Cast<Animal>().ToList();
```

Of course it's not the same thing, it's not actually covariance - you're actually creating another list, but it is a "workaround" so to speak.

In .NET 2.0, you can take advantage of array covariance to simplify the code:

```
List<Giraffe> giraffes = new List<Giraffe>();
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>(giraffes.ToArray());
```

But be aware that you're actually creating *two* new collections here.

Comment: I think these are quite good workarounds for my simple application. At least they're good for readability - not for performance.

Comment: @JohnAskew: I'm not sure what your point is here - there's no `Cast` method on `IList<T>`, it's the `Enumerable<T>.Cast<T2>` extension method, which takes an `IEnumerable<T>` and explicitly casts every element to `T2` and then returns it (as an `IEnumerable<T2>`, not an `IList<T2>`). It has nothing to do with `IList<T>` at all, save for the fact that `IList<T>` happens to inherit from `IEnumerable<T>` and thus supports the `Enumerable<T>` extension methods. There's no covariance whatsoever there.

Comment: I didn't see the reference to C# 3.5 and was referring to C# 4.0 where the IEnumerable<T> interface was updated to be IEnumerable<out T> and the Cast<T> method changed to use covariance:

IEnumerable<TResult> typedSource = source as IEnumerable<TResult>

rather than an iteration with explicit casting.