# c# casting question

Tags: c#, casting

If I have the following classes:

```
public class MyItems : List<MyItem>
{
..
}

public class MyItem : Item
{
..
}
```

How could I go about casting an instance of MyItems back down to `List<Item>`?  I've tried doing an explicit cast and I get an exception.

Comment: In C# 4 you will be able to cast it down to IEnumerable<Item>, but not IList<Item>.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, because C# doesn't support generic variance ([see here for discussion of terminology](http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2008/12/c-covariance-and-contravariance-by-example.html)), and even if it did, it wouldn't allow this case, because if you could cast MyItems to `List<Item>`, you could call `Add(someItemThatIsntAMyItem)`, which would violate type safety (because a MyItems can contain only MyItem objects, not arbitrary items).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase) (or search SO for "c# generic variance") for additional information about this issue and future changes in C# 4 (though these will not affect your specific case).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I figured out a different design to get what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I saw that was coming in 4.0.  Not available yet.

Comment: Nope, won't be coming in 4.0 because (a) C# 4 supports variance only for delegates and interfaces, not classes (sigh) and (b) even if it did support variance on classes, it wouldn't be safe for `List<T>` because T is in-out (variance is safe only if the type parameter appears only as inputs or only as outputs, not if it appears as both).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyList : IList<MyClass>
{
    List<MyClass> _list;


    //Implement all IList members like so
    public int IndexOf(MyClass item)
    {
        return _list.IndexOf(item);
    }


    //Then help the type system a bit with these two static methods.
    public static implicit operator List<MyClass> (MyList mylist)
    {
        return mylist._list;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyList (List<MyClass> list)
    {
        return new MyList() { _list = list;}
    }
```