# Casting Generic Types

Tags: vb.net, generics, casting

```
Public Function CastToT(Of T)(ByVal GenericType(Of Object) data) As GenericType(Of T)
   Return DirectCast(data, GenericType(Of T))
End Function
```

The above clearly does not work. Is there any way to perform this cast if I know that all objects inside data are in fact of Type T?

Comment: This is not possible, except for interfaces.

Comment: If you had written that as an answer instead of a comment, you would have just earned yourself 15 points... Thanks though.

Comment: It's a FAQ. E.g. see this for a detailed treatment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, except for interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot cast it directly. Presumably your `GenericType` is some kind of a container. You will just have to create a new instance of `GenericType(Of T)` and copy the contents into it, casting each object from `Object` to `T`. If `GenericType` was a `System.Collections.List(Of T)` then LINQ makes this very easy.

Comment: Thanks Evgeny. DotNET 2.0 only so no Linq for me. Writing a function that directcasts all the items is no problem, just wondered whether there was a dirty trick I could use.