# Shouldn't Covariance/Contravariance allow this in C# 4.5?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, covariance, contravariance

```
private Dictionary<Type, List<IDataTransferObject>> dataStore = new Dictionary<Type, List<IDataTransferObject>>();

public void Insert<T>(T dto) where T : IDataTransferObject
{
    if (!dataStore.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
    {
        dataStore.Add(typeof(T), new List<T>());
    }

    dataStore[typeof(T)].Add(dto);
}
```

The above code gives me a compile error on the dataStore.Add line because it doesn't like me trying to assign a `List<T>` to a `List<IDataTransferObject>`.  Since my method restricts T to only IDataTransferObject's shouldn't the covariance/contravariance stuff in .Net 4 allow this code?

I know I can change it to do new `List<IDataTransferObject>` and it will work, but I'm curious why the original code doesn't work.

Comment: [Skeet to the rescue.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase)

Comment: Maybe you're a little confused about the version numbers? If you're referring to .NET 4.5 (C# 5), there's the new [`IReadOnlyList<out T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx) interface which is **covariant** in its `T`. Note that in .NET only interfaces (and delegate types), not classes/structs, can be covariant. The reason why the `IReadOnlyList<>` can be made covariant, is that it only includes members that _read_ from the underlying list (no _write_). However, `IReadOnlyList<>` doesn't help you in your "impossible" problem, so .NET 4.5 is of no help here after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure a `List<SubClass>` isn't covariant to `List<BaseClass>`. `IEnumerable<T>` maybe, but not List as you can freely add a non-`T` (but still `IDataTransferObjects`) which would throw a runtime exception so it's caught at compile time.

While your code might be safe at runtime (as you use keys by type), the compiler doesn't know this.

```
List<Animal> animalList = new List<Animal>();
animalList.Add(new Dog()); //ok!

List<Cat> catList = new List<Cat>();
animalList = catList; //Compiler error: not allowed, but it's what you're trying to do
animalList.Add(new Dog()) //Bad stuff! Trying to add a Dog to a List<Cat>
```

What you're doing would work if you were trying to treat it as `IEnumerable<IDataTransferObject>` as those cannot by modified by code (unless you cast it first at which point it would pass/fail if you use a bad type). But `List` can definitely be altered by compile-time code.

EDIT: If you don't mind casting, and really want a `List<T>` (so your calling code is typesafe and not adding non-`T` objects once retrieved) you might do something like this:

```
private Dictionary<Type, object> dataStore = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

public void Insert<T>(T dto) where T : IDataTransferObject
{
    object data;
    if (!dataStore.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out data))
    {
        var typedData = new List<T>();
        dataStore.Add(typeof(T), typedData);
        typedData.Add(dto);
    }
    else
    {
        ((List<T>)data).Add(dto);
    }
}


//you didn't provide a "getter" in your sample, so here's a basic one
public List<T> Get<T>() where T : IDataTransferObject
{
    object data;
    dataStore.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out data);
    return (List<T>)data;
}
```

Calling code is like:

```
Insert(new PersonDTO());
Insert(new OrderDTO());
Insert(new PersonDTO());

List<PersonDTO> persons = Get<PersonDTO>();
List<OrderDTO> orders = Get<OrderDTO>();

Console.WriteLine(persons.Count); //2
Console.WriteLine(orders.Count); //1
```

So from the outside, all API usage is typesafe. Instead of `orders` being a `List<IDataTransferObject>` (which means you can add non-`OrderDTO` objects), it's strongly typed and cannot be mixed and matched.

Of course at this point, there's no real need to constrain to `IDataTransferObject`, but that's up to you and your API/design/usage.