# How to set a generic list of a type to a generic list of its interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

How to set a generic list of a type to a generic list of its interface?

I have a `Car` class which inherits from `ICar`.

I have a `Client` class which accepts a `List<ICar>` objects in the constructor, I don't want to explicitly write `List<Car>` for the `Client` class.

But it's not possible to set

```
var carsList = new List<Car>();
List<ICar> cars = carsList // compile error
var client = new Client(cars);
```

How would you achieve this?

I realized if I make it IList it would work but I'd have to explicitly cast my carsList object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to use the .NET Framework List and doing the type of implicit conversion you want.

I'll steal something from another thread to demonstrate the fundamental problem:

Consider:

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Giraffe>();
animals.Add(new Monkey());
```

Or using your code:

```
interface ICar{}
class Car:ICar{}
class BatMobile:ICar{}

List<ICar> cars = new List<Car>()
cars.Add(new BatMobile()) // We can't add a BatMobile to a List of Car.
```

IEnumerable is ok with this type of variance because you ensure the user cannot modify the collection via the IEnumerable interface. With a list this cannot be guaranteed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033931/299408

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly cast a `List<Car>` to a `List<ICar>`, because you could try to add a `OtherCar` to your `List<ICar>` hiding a `List<Car>` and that wouldn't work.

Instead you could:

- Make the constructor parameter a covariant interface, such as an `IEnumerable<Car>`, and create a list from it inside the constructor, or
- Convert the list outside the constructor via `List<ICar> cars = carsList.ToList<ICar>();`

Answer (score 1):

there are three way exists:

```
1) define carsList as List<ICar>
2) use framework 4.0 and IEnumerable<ICar>
3) manually convert
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the list as a List of ICars...

```
var carsList = new List<ICar>();
List<ICar> cars = carsList; // compile error gone :)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it the other way around.

```
var carsList = new List<ICar>(); // Hey, why not?
var client = new Client(cars);
```

Have you tried casting?

```
List<ICar> carsList = (List<ICar>)implementationList;
```