# Why doesn't .Net 4 allow me to pass in an array of an interface?

Tags: c#, collections, covariance

I have an array of Circle objects (where Circle implements IShape interface and i have a function that has a parameter of `List<IShape>` . . why can't i pass in my array of Circles into this ?

Visual studio gives me a build error saying  can't convert `List<Circle>` to `List<IShape>`

Comment: You mean you have a `List<Circle>` and a function `Foo(List<IShape> c)` and `Circle : IShape`?  Consider if `Foo` had the line: `c.Add(new Square())`.

Comment: This is an often asked question. Search for questions involving covariance on enumerable types.

Comment: Will IEnumerable<IShape> suffice?  Not all types are covariant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase

Comment: Because you cant convert directly convert `List<Circle>` to `List<IShape>`, But you should be able to pass it in as `myCircles.OfType<IShape>().ToList()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is because a function `Foo` can be implemented like this:

```
void Foo(IList<IShape> c)
{
    c.Add(new Square());
}
```

If you passed a `List<Circle>` to `Foo`, the provided type would not be capable of storing the `Square`, even though the type signatures claim it is okay. `IList<T>` is not [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29): the general `IList<Circle>` cannot be an `IList<IShape>` because it cannot support the addition of arbitrary shapes.

The fix is to use `IEnumerable<IShape>` to accept arguments in `Foo`, but that won't work in all cases. `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant: the specialized `IEnumerable<Circle>` fits the contract of the general `IEnumerable<IShape>`.

---

This behavior is also a Good Thing. The classic example of something that is covariant when it should not be is an array. The following code will compile, but will fail at runtime:

```
void Bar()
{
    // legal in C#:
    object[] o = new string[10];
    // fails with ArrayTypeMismatchException: can't store Int in a String[]
    o[0] = 10;
}
```

Comment: Actually, `IEnumerable<Circle>` will not be accepted by a method with the parameter `IEnumerable<IShape>` you have to cast the collection you pass to the function to an instance of `IEnumerable<IShape>` if the method signature is `Foo(IEnumerable<IShape> shapes)`.

Comment: @FrancisR.Griffiths-Keam, you are incorrect. As of .NET 4, IEnumerable<T> is covariant on T, which means IEnumerable<X> can be substituted as long as X derives from (or implements) T.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Ahh I missed that memo, thanks for putting the record straight.

Comment: It is probably also important to note that `IList<T>` does not have this same property (and *can't*).