# Why does IEnumerable not need a cast but a List does?

Tags: c#

Given the following LinqPad example:

```
void Main()
{   
    List<DbItem> dbItems = new List<DbItem>
    {
        new DbItem{Id = 4, SomeValue = "Value For 4", OtherValue = 1},
        new DbItem{Id = 19, SomeValue = "Value For 19", OtherValue = 2}
    };

    ListMethod(dbItems.Cast<IDbItem>().ToList());   <-+
    EnumerableMethod(dbItems);                      <-+
}                                                     |  
                                                      |
//    These are the methods are I asking about -------+

public void ListMethod(List<IDbItem> dbItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dbItems);
}
public void EnumerableMethod(IEnumerable<IDbItem> dbItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dbItems);
}
public class DbItem : IDbItem
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string SomeValue {get; set;}
    public int OtherValue {get; set;}
}   
public interface IDbItem 
{
    int Id {get; set;}
    string SomeValue {get; set;}
}
```

**Why can `EnumerableMethod` take the list directly while `ListMethod` needs a cast first?**

I get that an cast is happening from DbItem to IDbItem, but what is different about the IEnumerable that allows it to make the cast without an express request?

I imagine the answer involves the word Covariance, but I don't know enough about that to just figure it out myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this post about covariance](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/what-c-40-covariance-doesn-do.html). He gives an explanation and a way to make the code work without the cast. Lists are not covariant, but you can just change the method like so:

```
public void ListMethod<T>(List<T> dbItems) where T : IDbItem
{
    Console.WriteLine(dbItems);
}
```

Covariance is the ability to assign a more derived generic type to a base generic type. The reason `List` is not covariant is because you could do this:

```
class Animal {}
class Dog : Animal {}
class Cat : Animal {}

void someFunction()
{
    List<Animal> dogs = new List<Dog>();
    dogs.Add(new Cat());
}
```

`dogs` is really a list of dogs, not of animals. Therefore adding a `Cat` to it would be a problem, specifically causing a compiler error.

Comment: I get that a dog is really a list of dogs and not animals.  But then why does it work for IEnumerable?

Comment: `IEnumerable` does not have an `Add` method, so there's no fear of adding a `Cat` to `dogs`. Covariance is something that must be explicitly specified, and the guys who made `List` decided that it shouldn't be covariant for the reason above. The guys who made `IEnumerable` decided that it should be covariant.

Answer (score 3):

> I imagine the answer involves the word Covariance

Yes you are correct, The type parameter for `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant. so you can use either the type you specified or any type that is more derived

```
   public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

Where as `List<T>` type parameter is not covariant

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, 
    IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, 
    IEnumerable
```

Comment: Does the `out` keyword make IEnumerable covariant?  If so, why?  If not, then what does?

Comment: Yes, The out makes the type parameter covariant, why? that is a question for the C# language designers

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't cast a collection of x's to a collection of y's, even though x derives from y and therefore every x is a y.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase).

This is why the covariance and contravariance concepts were added to the language.

Unfortunately `List<T>` does not support these features.

Comment: .NET 4.0 / C# 4.0 only applies to generic interfaces and generic delegate declarations; it does not apply to concrete types (so it's not a support feature of List, but of all concrete types).