# ASP.NET MVC ViewBag list of anonymous class throws error on Count() method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, anonymous-types

I have a serverside code where I'm returning a list of anonymous class from the database:

```
    public ActionResult DisplayMap()
    {
        ViewBag.Checkins = (from locationUpdate in db.LocationUpdates
                            select new
                            {
                                locationUpdate,
                                locationUpdate.User
                            }).ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

At the Razor page, I want to get the count of this list:

```
@if (ViewBag.Checkins.Count() > 0)
{ ... }
```

However, it throws an error:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred 
in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code.

Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Count'
```

When I type `ViewBag.Checkins` in immediate window, I get:

```
ViewBag.Checkins
{System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType6<MY_APP.LocationUpdate,MY_APP.User>>}
    [0]: { locationUpdate = {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LocationUpdate_4532566693B61EF657DDFF4186F1D6802EA1AC8D5267ED245EB95FEDC596E129}, User = {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_816C8A417B45FE8609CD1F0076A5E6ECBAB0F309D83D2F8A7119044B1C6060CF} }
```

The `Checkins` object is indeed a `List`, and the data is correct. I've tried `Count`, `Length` too (without method call, just as properties) but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try <span>@ViewBag.Checkins.ToString()</span> and see what it outputs?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`ViewBag` is `dynamic`, while `Count` is an *extension* method, which isn't supported dynamically (it has to be bound *at compile time*).

You can either cast to an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`:

```
@if (((IEnumerable<dynamic>)ViewBag.Checkins).Count() > 0)
```

or use the static method directly:

```
@if (Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.Checkins) > 0)
```

Or create a strongly-typed model with a `Checkins` property and avoid `ViewBag` altogether.

**EDIT**

Since you're just wanting to check if the count is greater than 0, `Any` is more appropriate (and may save some processing time depending on the scenario):

```
@if (Enumerable.Any(ViewBag.Checkins))
```

Comment: that is a solid answer. forgot about extension methods not supporting dynamic binding. `Enumerable.Count` worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The viewbag is dynamic which make it an anonymous type generated as internal. It's better that you use view models instead.

and then call the view with its model, do something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel{
LocationUpdate LocationUpadte{get;set;}
User User{get;set;}
}

public ActionResult DisplayMap()
{
        var model = (from locationUpdate in db.LocationUpdates
                            select new MyViewModel
                            {
                                locationUpdate,
                                locationUpdate.User
                            }).ToList();
        return View(model);
}
```

then in you razor view

`@Model.Count()` will return the expected value

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your object since the viewbag is dynamic. For example:

```
var list = ViewBag.List as List<int>();
list.Count();
```

Comment: One wrinkle it that it's a list of an _anonymous type_.

Comment: you don't need to cast it.

Comment: I've tried casting to `List<object>` but it didn't work either (List<object> becomes null)

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Because it's _not_ a `List<object>`, it's a list of some _anonymous type_. You _could_ cast it to `IEnumerable<object>` since `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant.

Comment: but don't all types derive from `object`?

Comment: Yes but `List<T>` is not covariant (otherwise you could add _any_ object to the list).  See a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase).

Answer (score -4):

You can do this:

```
- @if(ViewBag.Checkins.Count > 0)
```