# Extension Method for List<InterfaceType> is not recognized

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I'm writing a couple of extension methods for some of our BusinessObjects

for example:

```
public static IBusinessObject GetBusinessObjectById<T>(this IBusinessObject businessObject, int id)
```

Now if i create a class:

```
public class Topic : IBusinessObject
```

I can then call my extension:

```
topic.GetBusinessObjectById<Topic>(id);
```

However that was the working stuff, now i tried to write a extension which focus on `List<IBusinessObject>`:

```
public static List<T> GetItems<T>(this List<IBusinessObject> list)
```

then creating a new List:

```
List<Topic> topics = new List<Topic>();
```

`topics.GetItems<Topic>();` gives the error

> `List<Topic>` does not contain a definition for GetItems

How can i write an extension method which focuses on a List instance of classes which have implemented my Interface?

Comment: I belive that `topics.Cast<IBusinessObject>().ToList().GetItems<Topic>()` will work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033921/284240

Comment: Can you change the parameter from `List<IBusinessObject>` into `IEnumerable<IBusinessObject>`?

Comment: @pwas, `topics.ToList<IBusinessObject>()` is simpler and will work just as well ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `List<Topic>` is *not* a `List<IBusinessObject>`, even though `Topic` implements `IBusinessObject`; that's because `List<T>` is not [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) (and anyway, only interfaces and delegates can be covariant, not classes).

If it was, it could cause all sorts of problems; for instance, consider this (hypothetical) extension method:

```
public static void Foo(this List<IBusinessObject> list)
{
    list.Add(new FooBusinessObject());
}
```

If you could call this method on a `List<BarBusinessObject>`, it would add an object of the wrong type, which would cause an exception at runtime.

If your `GetItems` method isn't going to modify the list, it should accept one of these interfaces instead of `List<IBusinessObject>`:

- `IEnumerable<IBusinessObject>`
- `IReadOnlyCollection<IBusinessObject>`
- `IReadOnlyList<IBusinessObject>`

All these interfaces are covariant.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of why `List<T>` is not covariant.  I haven't seen that before.

Answer (score 1):

An instance of a `List<Topic>` is not an instance of a `List<IBusinessObject>`.  While `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, `List<T>` is not.

On the other hand, a `List<Topic>` is also an `IEnumerable<Topic>`, which is itself an `IEnumerable<IBusinessObject>`.  Therefore if you redefine your extension method as

```
public static List<T> GetItems<T>(this IEnumerable<IBusinessObject> collection)
```

then you should have the function you're looking for.