# Inheritance and Generic Types

Tags: c#

i have a problem to create my code structure i don't now how to make it work

**the problem in `PlayListInfo<VerseTrack> ProgresList = new PlayListInfo<VerseTrack1>();`
where it connot be converted**

here is the code sample

```
public class PlayListInfo<_VerseTrack> : IPlayListInfo
    where _VerseTrack : VerseTrack
{
     public List<_VerseTrack> Tracks;
}

public class VerseTrack1: VerseTrack
{

}

public class VerseTrack2: VerseTrack
{

}


public class player
{
    PlayListInfo<VerseTrack> ProgresList;
}

public class player1:player
{
   PlayListInfo<VerseTrack> ProgresList = new PlayListInfo<VerseTrack1>();
}
public class player2:player
{
}
```

Comment: This should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase

Comment: i edit the question and correct it, it's "VerseTrack1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generic types aren't inherited based on their type parameters. A `PlayListInfo<QuranVerseTrack>` is *not* a `PlayListInfo<VerseTrack>`

You *could* do:

```
PlayListInfo<VerseTrack1> ProgresList = new PlayListInfo<VerseTrack1>();
```

and then treat all of the *items* like a `VerseTrack`, but it's unclear if that's what you *should* do.

or you could do:

```
PlayListInfo<VerseTrack> ProgresList = new PlayListInfo<VerseTrack>();
```

and then add `VerseTrack1` (or `VerseTrack2`) items to it (assuming it's a collection of some sort).

Side note:  `player1.ProgresList` is *hiding* the base property, not overriding it.

Comment: Agreed, and the type constraint he already has is sufficient for the limitation he's trying to set.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4.0 or higher, here's another workaround. I introduce you [*covariance* and *contravariance*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx)

```
Assuming A is convertible(implicit reference conversion is available) to B, 
X is covariant if X<A> is convertible to X<B>
```

Since covariance and contravariance only work with interface, you need to modify `IPlayListInfo` like this:

```
public interface IPlayListInfo<out _VerseTrack> 
  where _VerseTrack : VerseTrack
{
  // blah blah ... 
}
```

And this might work!

```
public class player1:player
{
  // PlayListInfo<VerseTrack> ProgresList = new PlayListInfo<VerseTrack1>(); // old one
  IPlayListInfo<VerseTrack> ProgressList = new PlayListInfo<VerseTrack1>() as IPlayListInfo<VerseTrack1>;
}
```