# Variance for interface tree structure

Tags: c#, .net, oop, covariance

I am struggling to cast in a tree hierarchy structure below is an example of the class hierarchy structure I would really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

I am unable to cast

```
var myobj2 = (IR<JB>)JR;
```

Classes:

```
public class BASEA{ }
public class B: BASEA{ }
public class C: B{ }

public interface IR<T> { }

public abstract class JR<T> : IR<T> where T : B
{ public abstract void SetRule(); }


public class Action: JB<C>
{
    public override void SetRule()
    {
       //Logic
    }
}

public static class RuleLib 
{

    public static void ApplyTest<T>(T obj, IR<T> JB) where T:B
    {
        var myobj2 = (IR<JB>)JR; //=> does not cast!
    }
}
public class Test
{
    [Test]
    public void demo()
    {
        var obj = new B();
        var action = new Action();
        RuleLib.ApplyRule(obj,action);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are looking for "C# variance for interfaces". Someone may find good duplicate or copy-paste existing answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase should give good starting point to reach `public interface IRule <out T>` as the change you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to work, your `IRule` interface needs to be covariant. The example given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows the following covariance:

```
IEnumerable<Derived> d = new List<Derived>();
IEnumerable<Base> b = d;
```

This is basically exactly what you're doing. So in your code all you need to do is write

```
public interface IRule<out T> { ... }
```

instead of

```
public interface IRule<T> { ... }
```

This makes it so that you can cast from an `IRule<U>` to `IRule<V>` where `U` is a subclass of `V` (e.g. casting from `IRule<ShiftAction>` to `IRule<Job>`).