# Is it possible to convert a generic list to a list of it's subclass?

Tags: c#

More specifically I have a Graph class, that contains a List of type Vertex .
I have another class that extends Graph called Graph2D, I'd like to **convert** a List of type Vertex to a List of type Vertex2D on Graph2D.

Is this possible?

Edit:Answered by shf301. Thanks.

Comment: You can't cast, but you can convert.

Comment: You might want to consider making the `Graph` class generic on the type of Vertex. You should also take a look at MSDN on co- and contra- variance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx to understand the limited circumstances when C# can help you with this problem.

Comment: You can't cast (explanation in [linked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase) ), so if you are fine with conversion/creating new - make sure to update your post so provided conversions answers can be on-topic and question can be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to cast a list to a list of it's subclasses.  There is no reasonable way this could work without breaking type safety.  Consider the following code if it were possible

```
List<Vertex> list1 = new List<Vertex>();
list1.Add(new Vertex());
List<Vertex2D> list2 = (List<Vertex2D>)list1;
Vertex2D vertex2d = list2[0];  // Oh no the first element is a Vertex!
```

The list list would have to throw an `InvalidCastException` since you can't convert a `Vertex` `to a Vertex2D`.

However I suspect that your real issue is you want the list of vertex's in `Vertex2D` that was inherited from `Vertex` to change type.  This is you have:

```
class Graph {
     public List<Vertex> Vertices { get; set; }
}

class Graph2D : Graph {
    // Now I want vertices to only contain Vertex2D!
}
```

You can accomplish this my making Graph generic on Vertex:

```
class GraphBase<TVertex> where TVertex : Vertex {
     public List<TVertex> Vertices { get; set; }
}

class Graph : GraphBase<Vertex> {
}

class Graph2D : GraphBase<Vertex2D> {
}
```

This does break the inheritance relationship between Graph and Graph2D.  If that's important I'd suggest implementing a non-generic interface.  This interface can rely on the fact that [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) is [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) on T:

```
interface IGraph {
     IEnumerable<Vertex> Vertices { get;}
}

 class GraphBase<TVertex> : IGraph where TVertex : Vertex {
     public List<TVertex> Vertices { get; set; }
     IEnumerable<Vertex> IGraph.Vertices { get { return Vertices; }}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "There is **no** reasonable way..."?

Answer (score -1):

Linq to the rescue!!

```
var casted = TheVertexList.Cast<Vertex2D>().ToList();
```

Comment: This creates a new list, it doesn't cast it