# Typecast an generic object in its generic version

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I've an interface which states:

```
public interface IMyType<T> where T: IMySubType {
    event EventHandler<IMyType<T>, EventArgs<T>> OnSomething;
    IEnumerable<T> AvailableThings{get;}
    void Start();
}
```

I've a `List<IMyType<IMySubType>>`, how can I add a `IMyType<SubTypeImplementation>` to this list? (`SubTypeImplementation` herits from the `IMySubType` interface.

I tried to put my `T`generic type as covariant, but it doesn't seems to work with an interface using this type as event(not sure to know why).

So, how can I store, iterate and call the start method on each element of the list?

Because currently my other alternative is to create a new interface without the genericity, and make a double implementation(because in most case I need to have this genericity.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Have you tried just adding the object? Do you get a compilation error?

Comment: `System.EventArgs` is not a generic type. Why do you have it used as generic? Same goes for `System.EventHandler`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @o_weisman : Runtime error saying that I cannot typecast this + Resharper warning me.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Sorry, `EventArgs<T> ` is our own object, which herits from `EventArgs`

Comment: @recursive Not sure to understand what you mean?

Comment: It was a reply to @DmytroShevchenko.  He said there is no generic `EventHandler`, but there is.

Comment: @recursive the one you linked has one type argument, while the one OP is using has two

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko:  I understand what you mean now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
public interface IMyType { }

public interface IMyType<T> : IMyType where T : IMySubType
{
    event EventHandler<IMyType<T>, EventArgs<T>> OnSomething;
    IEnumerable<T> AvailableThings{get;}
    void Start();
}
```

Your list would be of type `List<IMyType>`:

```
List<IMyType> myList = new List<IMyType>();
myList.Add(implementation1); // implementation1 is of type IMyType<SubTypeImplementation>
myList.Add(implementation2); // implementation2 is of type IMyType<SubTypeImplementation2>
```

Of course, the drawback would be that you will need to cast each element on the list in order to use it:

```
var impl = (IMyType<SubTypeImplementation>)list[0];
impl.Start();
```

---

Anyway, I wouldn't use generics in this situation.

My `IMyType` would look like this:

```
public interface IMyType
{
     event EventHandler<IMySubType, EventArgs<IMySubType>> OnSomething;
     IEnumerable<IMySubType> AvailableThings { get; }
     void Start();
}
```

Comment: Well, I cannot know  which generic type I receive

Comment: Edit bis: Like I said, the main use of this class is to have the same behavior for different kind of sub items. But in my new case, I need to be able to get them anonymously and I wanted to know if there was a way to do it

Comment: @J4N Polymorphism doesn't work on generics. `IEnumerable<int>`, for example, is not the same type as (nor does it inherit from) `IEnumerable<object>`. This is the only way I see of working around your problem.

Comment: @J4N Lists do not support covariance. See [C# - Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase)

Comment: Any other IEnumerable type that would support it?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I add an `IMyType<SubTypeImplementation>` to this list?

`IMyType` needs to be covariant for this to work.  Being covariant means that the generic type can *only* be included in the output of functions.  Since your interface includes an `EventHandler` that takes the generic type as part of the *input*, your interface cannot be covariant.

Let's change you interface names to understand why.  Suppose you run a zoo and want to distinguish "view-only" cages from "normal" cages.  So you have two interfaces:

```
IViewOnlyCage<out T>
{
    public T View();
}

ICage<T>
{
    public Add(T animal);
}
```

Now consider two "lists" of cages:

```
List<IViewOnlyCage<IAnimal>> list1;
List<ICage<IAnimal>> list2;
```

And I populate the lists as such:

```
list1.Add(new Cage<Tiger>());
list1.Add(new Cage<Deer>());
```

In the first case, a list of view-only cages is perfectly reasonable.  Each cage contains some type of animal, so there's no danger of the two animals ending up together.

But consider the second - with an `Add` method I could do this:

```
list2.Add(new Cage<Tiger>());

ICage<IAnimal> cage = list2[0];  // a reference to the tiger cage
cage.Add(new Deer());  //uh-oh... bad news for the deer
```

Since your interface contains indirect *inputs*, something like this would be possible:

```
List<IMyType<IMySubType>> list = new List<IMyType<IMySubType>>();

list.Add(new IMyType<SubTypeImplementation>());

IMyType<IMySubType> item = list[0];  // seems OK

item.OnSomething += new EventHandler(IMyType<SecondSubType>, EventArgs<SecondSubType>);
```

but the *actual* generic type is `SubTypeImplementation`, not `SecondSubType`, so you have a type conflict.

The easiest changes seems to be to move the event handler to a different interface.  You can then make `IMyType` covariant and have a `List<IMyType<IMySubType>>`.

Comment: okay. Is there a workaround to have event that include the generic type?

Comment: @J4N Not that will make `IMyType` covariant.  You'll have to live with lists of more specific types.

Comment: Well, This doesn't solve my issue unfortunately, I need to get the specific version in many case. Also, I understand the boxing issue, but in my case, I don't see how I can have such issue, since I always use this type as "output", and the only way I could use it is to be "more generic". I don't return list of anything, I use a list to store the generic version of my class

Comment: But the settable event handler allows an input of a "derived" type, which is not allowed.  I'll add some options, but no magic bullets.