# What is the difference between Cast List<object> and Cast IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#, class, generics, interface, casting

I tried to make a conversion from object (the object contains a `List<Apple>`) to `List<object>`, and it fails with an exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List[list_cast_object_test.Apple]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]'.

When I have replaced `List` with `IEnumerable` or `IList` (an interface) it works well, and I don't understand the difference....

The code looks like:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        object resultObject = GetListAsObject();

        // this cast works fine, it's normal...
        var resAsIt = (List<Apple>)resultObject;

        // also when I use a generic interface of 'object' cast works fine
        var resAsIEnumerable = (IEnumerable<object>)resultObject;

        // but when I use a generic class of 'object' it throws me error: InvalidCastException
        var resAsList = (List<object>)resultObject;
    }

    private object GetListAsObject() {
        List<Apple> mere = new List<Apple>();
        mere.Add(new Apple { Denumire = "ionatan", Culoare = "rosu" });
        mere.Add(new Apple { Denumire = "idared", Culoare = "verde" });
        return (object)mere;
    }
}
public class Apple {
    public string Denumire { get; set; }
    public string Culoare { get; set; }
}
```

Someone may explain me what it happens? What is the difference between cast to a generic interface and cast to a generic class?

Comment: ``IEnumerable<T>`` is covariant

Comment: It's the [lion eats giraffe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033921/284240) problem. `IEnumerable<>` is safe for giraffes because you can't [add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) lions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` is an interface, and since the type `T` is defined covariant (it is actually `IEnumerable<out T>`, note the `out`), you can cast the `T` to a base implementation, so `IEnumerable<object` is a valid cast on your list of type `List<Apple>`.

However, the type `List<Apple>` is not equal to the type `List<object>`, nor does the list `List<Apple>` derived from `List<object>`. The type parameter on `List<T>` is *not* covariant, hence that cast is invalid.

Answer (score 6):

It is because in `IEnumerable<T>` `T` is covariant while in `List<T>` `T` does not support Covariance.

See more about [Covariance and Contraviance in c#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

If you want to do thing like that you then have to use `ToList<T>()` overload which will wrap it to object type like:

```
 List<object> result = resultObject.ToList<object>();
```

Here we are able to convert `List<Apple>` to `List<Object>` due to new `List<T>` creation where `T` is of type `Object` but we cannot cast the original `List<Apple>` reference to `List<object>`.

In this case it will create instance of `Object` type and will store reference to your type as reference of type `object` , but in case of Value Types or strcuts it will have boxing cost.

Comment: resultObject it's an object class, and it doesn't have ToList function.

Comment: `ToList` is an extension method. Add the statement `using System.Linq;` on top of your class.

Comment: @PatrickHofman OP is returning `List<T>` as of type `Object` from method