# Cast IEnumerable<object> to List<object>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code:

```
public IList<MyObject> GetSomeData(string inputParam)
{
    var temp = repository.GetData(inputParam);
    var list = temp as List<MyObject>;
    return list;
}
```

The return value of repository.GetData is `IEnumerable<IMyObject>`

When I look at the value of temp, it has 400+ records.  The moment I cast it to list, it becomes null.  Why is this cast not possible?

Comment: `var list = temp.ToList();`

Comment: Because your `IEnumerable` is not a `List`.  `IEnumerable`s come in many shapes and sizes, and many of them are not `List`s. Try using `.ToList()` instead.

Comment: Don't use `as` to cast in C#. Use `(List<MyObject>)temp` unless you want `list` to be `null` if `temp` is not a `List<MyObject>`.

Comment: Please see this [previous question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033921/1260204) and also [Covariance and Contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx). Also make sure that `MyObject` actually implements `IMyObject` and that the instances returned in the list are all of concrete type `MyObject`.

Comment: Why don't you just return an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` ? There is no reason to return a `List` in that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the underlying object of the value returned from `repository.GetData` matches what you are trying to cast it to then the result will always be `null`. Because the generic element types of the method and what is actually return from `repository.GetData` are different you will need to do some conversions to get the desired result

Assuming that `MyObject` implements `IMyObject` I can think of at least to ways using `System.Linq` to get the result you seek.

**Option 1: `Cast<T>()`**

> Casts the elements of an System.Collections.IEnumerable to the specified type.

First convert the content of `temp` using the `Cast<MyObject>()` linq extension and then use the `ToList<T>()` extension method to get you resulting `IList<MyObject>`

```
public IList<MyObject> GetSomeData(string inputParam)
{
    //repository.GetData returns IEnumerable<IMyObject>
    var temp = repository.GetData(inputParam);
    var list = temp.Cast<MyObject>().ToList();
    return list;
}
```

**Option 2: `OfType<T>()`**

> Filters the elements of an System.Collections.IEnumerable based on a specified type.

Filter the content of `temp` using the `OfType<MyObject>()` linq extension and then use the `ToList<MyObject>()` extension method to get you resulting `IList<MyObject>`

```
public IList<MyObject> GetSomeData(string inputParam)
{
    //repository.GetData returns IEnumerable<IMyObject>
    var temp = repository.GetData(inputParam);
    var list = temp.OfType<MyObject>().ToList();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: IEnumerable already implements ToList(). It will infer the generic type as a list of T, so, there is no need of doing this unless MyObject is inherited from the generic class

Comment: @Octanic IEnumerable does not implement ToList().  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Indeed, I should've refer it as IEnumerable<T>... Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx @Nkosi

Comment: Those are extension methods. IEnumerable<T> `Exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a collection of a specified type.` as such it only had one method (single responsibility)  `GetEnumerator()`

Comment: Yes, but practically speaking, it is not necessary to use cast or oftype just to perform tolist.  @Nkosi

Comment: The OP stated that repository.GetData returns IEnumerable<IMyObject>. note the `IMyObject` Interface. the OfType and/or Cast is to convert the interface to the concrete type `MyObject`

Comment: if you call ToList on `IEnumerable<IMyObject>` while the method is suppose to return IList<MyObject> you get a type mismatch. hence the conversion.

Comment: That's correct. I've missed the "I" on the myobject, so, that's a good solution! Thanks for the patience explaining this!

Answer (score 4):

It returns null because that `IEnumerable` isn't actually a list.  The cast will only succeed if that particularly `IEnumerable` happens to be a `List`, instead of some other type of sequence.  If you want to have a list, you will need to create a new list and add the items from the sequence into that list.

Comment: the problem of when I do .ToList is that it wanst `List<IMyObject>` as return type and I need to serialize the object.  I can't seem to serialize it the object if I return it like that.

Comment: @Bagzli Then just use the `List` constructor.