# Invalid cast from C<string> to C<object>

Tags: c#

I've created a class like:

```
class C<T> {}
```

Then

```
C<string> cs = new C<string>();
C<object> co = (C<object>)cs;
```

.Net throws an `InvalidCastException` me:

> It's not possible to cast a object of type C'1[System.String] to C'1[System.Object]

Any help?

Comment: What you are looking for is [co-variance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654055.aspx).  That is only possible with interfaces and delegates.

Comment: I'd expect that to fail to *compile* rather than throwing an exception. It's just not valid. A `C<string>` *isn't* a `C<object>`.

Comment: You should get a compile-time error of: `error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'C<string>' to 'C<object>'`

Comment: Just another [lion eats giraffe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033921/284240) question

Comment: *Why* did you create such a class? What are you trying to achieve? This sounds like the XY Problem: You have an issue with X, assume the solution is Y and ask about Y when you run into trouble. If you wanted to treat generic classes in an abstract way, you should use a generic interface, not try to cast between generic classes

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: No, because there's no value (other than null) for which the cast is valid. It's like trying to do `Button b = (Button) new StringReader("");`. I validated that it failed to compile, by trying it...