# C#: Passing List<String> to Construct which accept List<object>

Tags: c#, casting, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a List to a constructer which takes List.

Constructor

```
public Constructor (List<IData> data) { ... }
```

Calling Constructor

```
var a = new Constructor (new List<source> ()); This is failed
```

source is subclass of IData where IData is an interface.

If I passing it like that, I will get the exception.

But if I cast it like this : `var a = (new List<string>()).Cast<object>()`, 
it become messy. Later, if I want to use string functions, I will need to cast the object back to string before I can call the string function.

Comment: Change your constructor to be `IEnumerable<IData> data` - and you will be able to pass in a `List<source>`

Comment: How does it work. Why the other way not working

Comment: I lost the Count property when using IEnumerable. I need to use it on my xamarin android inside the PagerAdapter class.

Comment: Because `IEnumerable<T>` is defined as being covariant. In short: It also makes a contract that you can never add to an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can only read from it. Therefore, it's safe to allow `IEnumerable<A>` to be cast to `IEnumerable<B>` where `A : B`. `List<T>` is *not* covariant, and you can add to the collection, so you cannot do that.

Comment: Good to understand.. In my scenario may not be the right way though

Comment: See also this post: Put a lion into a zoo of giraffes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase

Comment: @Simon You can still use `Count()` rather than `Count`. I can't off the top of my head think of an interface that `List<T>` implements which is covariant and exposes `Count`. So, if `Count()` is too expensive for your use case, you may need to create your own covariant interface and implement a custom collection

Comment: Ok that is system.Linq.Enumerable not System.Collection. Does System.Linq.IEnumerable Count function an expensive to use ....

Comment: @Simon It's not necessarily expensive, no. It depends on your use-case. Does your list have billions of elements? Then it might be an issue. You'll need to investigate yourself whether or not it's a bottle neck. It's unlikely to be a bottleneck, but I figured I'd mention it, as it *is* more expensive than the `Count` property.

Comment: Probably not many data in each of the list ...

Comment: I assume if you use the generic interface within your methods signature and pass an instance of `List<T>` (as in your example) to it the `Count()`-method will simply call the property `Count` making it an O(1)-operation. No need to iterate whole collection.