# Unable to pass child in base parameter

Tags: c#, inheritance, parameters

I'm trying to pass a child object in a Base class defined parameter but it doesn't work. I think I'm doing something wrong but I can't seem to figure out what.

This is the method I'm trying to execute:

```
 public static Tuple<List<AutoTaskBriljant>, List<TransactionResult>> MakeXMLFromObjectList(List<AutoTaskBriljant> lstObjects, 
        Func<BriljantObjects, IEnumerable<TransactionResult>> CheckObjectInput, string name)
```

The base class I was talking about is AutoTaskBriljant

I'm trying to execute the method here:

```
public static Tuple<List<Herstelling>, List<TransactionResult>> MakeXMLFromHerstellingenList(List<HerstellingTicket> lstTickHerst, string fileNameStart)
    {            
        return TransactionHelper.MakeXMLFromObjectList(lstTickHerst, CheckHerstellingInput, fileNameStart);
    }
```

The class HerstellingTicket is a child of AutoTaskBriljant

```
public class HerstellingTicket:AutoTaskBriljant
{
    public HerstellingTicket(Ticket atObj, Herstelling brObj) : base(atObj, brObj)
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And "it doesn't work" means what exactly? Does it compile?

Comment: ``List<HerstellingTicket>`` is never equal to ``List<AutoTaskBriljant>``

Comment: The code doesn't compile: I get the following error output: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HerstellingTicket>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AutoTaskBriljant>

Comment: Even this won't work:
List<AutoTaskBriljant> lstATBR = new List<HerstellingTicket>(); - Same error

Comment: They're not the same thing, so why would you expect that to work? If you had a `List<Apple>` that you were allowed to cast to `List<Fruit>`, you'd then be allowed to add an `Orange` to your `List<Apple>`... which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase)

Comment: @CharlesMager: List<Fruit> lstFruit = List<Apples> lstApples should work right? I thought that was what I'm doing here

Comment: @JasperCallens no, that's exactly what I just described. You'd be allowed to add `Orange` to `lstFruit`, which can't work as it's actually a `List<Apple>`.  `List<T>` is not covariant. I suggest reading about [covariance and contravariance in generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Oh okay I get it now! Thank you @CharlesMager