# In C#, why is this conversion from list of objects to list of interfaces throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, collections, casting, covariance

In C#, I have a class **MyObj** that implements an interface **IMyInterface**.

I now have a collection of lists of MyObj class:

```
IEnumerable<List<MyObj>> myObjGroups
```

and I want to convert / cast it to

```
IEnumerable<List<IMyInterface>> myInterfaceGroups
```

and everything I have tried has thrown an exception.

**An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyObj]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IMyInterface]'.**

I have tried:

```
IEnumerable<List<IMyInterface>> myInterfaceGroups= new List<List<IMyInterface>>(myObjGroups.Cast<List<IMyInterface>>());
```

and:

```
IEnumerable<List<IMyInterface>> myList = myObjGroups.Cast<List<IMyInterface>>();
```

and both seems to throw exceptions at run time.

Any suggestions on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: `List<MyObj>` is not a `List<IMyInterface>` so the cast is invalid. You could use `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IMyInterface>>`. If you need inner lists then `myObjGroups.Select(l => l.Cast<IMyInterface>().ToList())`.

Comment: Like @Lee says, a `List<MyObj>` is not a `List<IMyInterface>`. That is because `List<T>` is not covariant in `T` (it is not `List<out T>`). That is because the class has members, such as the `Add` method, that make covariance impossible. An interface such as `IReadOnlyList<out T>` would work. An `IReadOnlyList<MyObj>` is an `IReadOnlyList<IMyInterface>` if just `MyObj` is a reference type implementing `IMyInterface`. And also `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it the following way:

```
IEnumerable<List<IMyInterface>> myInterfaceGroups = myObjGroups
    .Select(l => l.Select(o => (IMyInterface)o).ToList());
```

Or if you prefer using the `Cast<T>()` extension method:

```
IEnumerable<List<IMyInterface>> myInterfaceGroups = myObjGroups
    .Select(l => l.Cast<IMyInterface>().ToList());
```

**EDIT: A bit of explanation**

To better understand why did you get the `InvalidCastException` exception, let's try to decompose your original expression:

```
IEnumerable<List<IMyInterface>> myInterfaceGroups = 
    new List<List<IMyInterface>>(myObjGroups.Cast<List<IMyInterface>>());
```

This is equivalent to:

```
IEnumerable<List<IMyInterface>> myObjGroupsAsInterfaceList = myObjGroups
    .Cast<List<IMyInterface>>()
    .ToList();

IEnumerable<List<IMyInterface>> myInterfaceGroups = new List<List<IMyInterface>>(myObjGroupsAsInterfaceList);
```

The `Cast<T>()` extension method just iterates through the items and tries to cast each item to type `T`. We could replace the functionality of `Cast<T>()` extension method combined with `ToList<T>()` with the following snippet:

```
List<List<IMyInterface>> myObjGroupsAsInterfaceList = new List<List<IMyInterface>>();
foreach (List<MyObj> myObjGroup in myObjGroups)
{
    List<IMyInterface> myObjGroupAsInterface = myObjGroup; // Compile error!
    myObjGroupsAsInterfaceList.Add(myObjGroupAsInterface);
}
```

So the root problem is that you cannot assign a `List<MyObj>` object to a variable of type `List<IMyInterface>`.

To find more explanation on why the above is not possible, take a look on the following question: [C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something wrong. You can't cast an `IEnumerable` to a `List`. A list is an actual metrialized collection of data, while an run-time `IEnumerable` needs to be iterated over in order to retrieve the data.

To solve your problem, you need to Cast to `IEnumerable<IMyInterface>`:

Check a working Fiddle: [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nQ2Eiu) (Same below)

```
public class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<List<MyObj>> Get()
    {
        yield return new List<MyObj>();
        yield return new List<MyObj>();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        IEnumerable<List<MyObj>> myObjGroups = Get();

        var result = myObjGroups.Cast<IEnumerable<IMyInterface>>();

        foreach(var val in result)
            Console.WriteLine(val.Count());
    }
}
```