# Whats wrong with: IList<IList<int>> myIList = new List<List<int>>();

Tags: c#, list

I am really confused about this List and IList things...and hope someone could help me out, THANKS!

My Question is about the second statement:

1. `IList<int> myIList1 = new List<int>();` (O)
2. `IList<IList<int>> myIList2 = new List<List<int>>();` (X)
3. `IList<IList<int>> myIList3 = new List<IList<int>>();`  (O)

I can understand that statement 1,3 works, but why statement 2 failed?

Comment: Because generics don't work that way

Comment: Keep giraffes safe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase [More reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess I have some clue about this.