# Using generic contravariant with IList and IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm learning C# generics and making some dummy code for testing purposes. So, I'm testing the [in Generic Modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-generic-modifier), which specifies that the type parameter is contravariant.

Given the below interface:

```
public interface IInterfaceTest<in T>
{
    void Method(T value);
    void Method(IList<T> values);
    void Method(IEnumerable<T> values);
}
```

When compiling, I'm getting the error message:

> [CS1961] Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly
>   valid on 'IInterfaceTest.Method(IList)'. 'T' is contravariant.

The error is related only with the line `void Method(IEnumerable<T> values)`. If this line is removed, all works fine.

**So my question is:** Why can I use the generic contravariant with `IEnumerable` but does not with `IList`? Am I forgot something?

Thanks.

Comment: `IList<T>` is not, and cannot be, covariant.

Comment: @SLaks: I think OP gets that, but why? (which will help me as well)

Comment: Because it's mutable. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033921/34397

Comment: tl;dr: `IEnumerable<SubclassOfT>` won't return anything less specialized than T, so that's OK. `List<SubclassOfT>.Add(SubclassOfT)` *requires* an argument more specialized than `T`.

Comment: Ed nailed it.  The simplified rule is: covariant type parameters can only be used to take something _out_, and contravariant can only be used to put something _in_.  Hence the declarations `out` and `in`.

Comment: Because, for a type parameter `T` with variance, the variance is effectively reversed for input types' relationships with `T` (but the same for output types' relationships).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question why it's not allowed for `IList<T>` has been answered in the comments and linked questions already: `IList<T>` is invariant in `T` and so a contra-variant `T` *cannot* be used here whatsoever.

What puzzled me at first is the fact that `Method(IEnumerable<T>)` is allowed here. The strange thing is that **variance is "turned around"** when you use the `T` as a type argument for **another generic type**.

Imagine this.

```
public interface ITestInterface<in T>
{
    void Method(IEnumerable<T> e);
    IEnumerable<T> GetMethod(); // illegal
}
public class Animal {}
public class Lion : Animal [}
public class Gnu : Animal {}

ITestInterface<Animal> animals;
ITestInterface<Lion> lions;
ITestInterface<Gnu> gnus;
```

Now the contra-variance of `ITestInterface<in T>` in `T` tells us that you can do

```
lions = animals;
```

And when you call `lions.Method(e)`, you can only provide an `IEnumerable<Lion>`. So the code of `Method` can only enumerate `Lion`s, which *are* all `Animals` as `animals.Method()` expects. Everything is fine.

On the other hand, the `IEnumerable<T> GetMethod()` is illegal, because:

```
gnus = animals;
```

is legal, and now `gnu.GetMethod()` would return an `IEnumerable<Animal>` where you'd expect an `IEnumerable<Gnu>`. And when you iterated, suprising animals could wait in that sequence.

Comment: The variance with respect to `T` is "turned around" for _inputs_ that have a relationship with `T`.  Outputs must have the same variance with respect to `T`.  For example, `Action<T> GetMethod()` would be valid because `Action<-T>` varies with `T` in the same way as `ITestInterface<-T>`.  Other than that, good answer.