# Contra/Covariance issue when assigning to Lazy<>

Tags: c#, covariance, contravariance

```
private void AMethod<T>() where T : Control, new()
{
    Lazy<T> lazyControl = new Lazy<T>(() => new T());

    Lazy<Control> a = lazyControl;
}
```

I get the following error on the last line.

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Lazy<T>' to
'System.Lazy<System.Windows.Forms.Control>'
```

I get that T could be a more specific type, but I don't get why I can't assign it to the Lazy variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there were an `ILazy<T>` interface, it could be declared as `ILazy<out T>`, and all would be well in your example: the `T` *is* only used in an output position, effectively.

However, `Lazy<T>` is a class. Covariance/contravariance can only be specified for delegates and interfaces, so `Lazy<T>` can't specify its covariance.

Therefore `Lazy<Control>` is incompatible with `Lazy<T>`, which is why the assignment isn't working. It's definitely frustrating, given that with the current API at least, it would be "safe" for it to be covariant, from a caller perspective.

(If you need this all over the place, you could declare your own `ILazy<out T>` interface and then write an implementation of that interface to wrap a `Lazy<T>`. I suspect that's more trouble than it's worth though.)

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. I did know that co/contravariance only work on interfaces. Thanx much.

Comment: Since the class `Lazy<T>` is not sealed, we can simply write the following and implement only the required members for the specific use case:
`public interface ILazy<out T> { T Value { get; } }` and `public class CovariantLazy<T>(Func<T> valueFactory) : Lazy<T>(valueFactory), ILazy<T> { }`.

Answer (score 4):

> I get that `T` could be a more specific type, but I don't get why I can't assign it to the Lazy variable.

A `Lazy<T>` has no relationship with a `Lazy<Control>`, just as little as a `Lazy<Base>` has any relationship with `Lazy<Derived>`.

Just because `Derived` derives from `Base` and you can do this:

```
Base b = new Derived();
```

...it doesn't mean that you can do this:

```
Lazy<Base> b = new Lazy<Derived>();
```

The type `Lazy<Derived>` does not derive from `Lazy<Base>`. @Jon Skeet explains this well here:

[C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase)