# Redefining list's content type

Tags: c#, list

Okay, this might be another stupid question to ask in a strict-type programming language, but...

```
public class Parent
{
    public List<Parent> list_of = new List<Parent>;
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public List<Child> list_of = new List<Child>;
}
```

Basically, what I am asking, is it possible to change list's "content" type in children classes?

Comment: Now that I think of it, just having two seperate lists in these classes could work. But the question of "overriding"/redefining stands.

Comment: you could leave it as List<Parent> and that would still be valid to store child instances in it, you could use list_of.OfType<Child> to return them as child instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, no. About overriding:

- It is not possible to override a field
- You can override a `virtual` property or function
- You can't change type when overriding anything (even type parameter of generic type)

But you can *hide* field/property/function with a `new` keyword and change type:

```
public class Parent
{
    public List<Parent> ListOf = new List<Parent>();
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public new List<Child> ListOf = new List<Child>();
}
```

It is not overriding, there you still can access `Parent`'s `ListOf` field, but only if you cast `Child` to `Parent`.

Also, there should be mentioned that you can treat `ISomeGeneric<Child>` type as `ISomeGeneric<Parent>` type only if they are covariant (declared as `ISomeGeneric<out T>`). `List<T>` isn't covariant ([here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase)), so `List<Child>` can't be treated as `List<Parent>`, these are two different types.
But `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, so you can make `ListOf` a property, change it's type to `IEnumerable<Parent>` and instantiate it with a `IEnumerable<Child>` in a derived class:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<Parent> ListOf { get; set; } = new List<Parent>();
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public override IEnumerable<Parent> ListOf { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
}
```

But even there you can't change property type `IEnumerable<Parent>` to `IEnumerable<Child>` when overriding.