# Why does mutability preclude covariance?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, parametric-polymorphism

I'm trying to understand how covariance works (in general, though my examples will be in C#) and what governs when a generic type can be covariant. Assume we have a class `Animal` with subclasses `Cat` and `Dog`. I get why a read-only type such as `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, allowing this code to compile:

```
IEnumerable<Animal> initialAnimalEnumerable = new List<Cat> {new Cat() };
IEnumerable<Animal> addedAnimalEnumerable = initialAnimalEnumerable.Append(new Dog());
```

because the elements of the enumerable can only be treated as type `Animal`; the information that they're Cats/Dogs specifically is lost. What I don't understand is why this can't apply with mutable collections such as `List<T>`:

```
List<Animal> initialAnimalList = new List<Cat> {new Cat() }; // error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'List<Cat>' to 'List<Animal>'
initialAnimalList[0] = new Dog();
```

Explanations on questions like [C# variance problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033921/5847190) seem to assume that this would cause a problem, because we're trying to add a `Dog` to a `List<Cat>`...but why is it still treated as a `List<Cat>` instead of a `List<Animal>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming a simple case where the only reference to the `List<Cat>` was the one used in assigning `initialAnimalList`. What if instead of creating a new object/reference you were instead assigning from another existing variable:

E.g.:

```
var cats = new List<Cat> {new Cat() };
List<Animal> initialAnimalList = cats; // error CS0266
initialAnimalList[0] = new Dog();
```

We still have `cats`. It's type hasn't magically changed to `List<Animal>` due to some later assignment, and any later code that accesses `cats` is entitled to assume it won't find a `Dog` in there.

The assignment doesn't change the type of the object.

Comment: Got it, thanks. This scenario is what I was missing in the explanations I read.