# Can't cast GenericClass<DerivedClass> to GenericClass<BaseClass>

Tags: c#, generics, casting, radix, derived

I'm creating a Container that can store any type of data. 
To get data from container i make method: 
`AnyTypeResult<T> Get<T>(string name)` - that returns from the container data that is registered as "name" and cast it to T.
The business logic requires that when we Add data to container as GenericType of DerivedClass it is possible to Get it as GenericType of BaseClass.
What is the best way to do it.

The same issue is when we want to cast `List<B>` to `List<A>`. It can be done witch Linq extension method `Cast<T>`

```
public class A {}
public class B : A {}
public class C<T> {}

var a = new C<A>();
var b = new C<B>();

var x = (C<A>)b; // cannot convert type
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033921/10608418 might be interesting. Basically the problem is that while everything comming out of a `List<B>` is also of type `A`, if you could cast it it would then be valid to also add an object of type `A` to a `List<B>` which obviously is not allowed.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0OMJwi

Comment: @Selvin IC what you did there;-) (sorry couldn't resist)

Comment: @Selvin IC = I see

Comment: Sorry @Selvin, was a bad joke. And @H D. The `Cast<T>` method of Linq doesn't cast it to a  a `List<A>` it becomes an `IEnumerable<A>` (allowed since objects only come out of an `IEnumerable<out T>`) and if you call `ToList()` on that it actually creates a new list of type `List<A>`. So there's not real cast of a `List<B>` to a `List<A>` being done.