# Error on casting a instance to Generic parent

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a problem to cast to generic parent,
this is my codes

```
    public interface IEvent
    {
    }

    public interface IEventHandler<TEvent> where TEvent : IEvent
    {
        Task Handle(TEvent evt);
    }

    public class PersonCreatedEvent : IEvent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonCreatedEventHandler : IEventHandler<PersonCreatedEvent>
    {
        public async Task Handle(PersonCreatedEvent evt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("done");
        }
    }
```

And my code for casting is this:

```
    var handler = new PersonCreatedEventHandler();

    // exception occurred on this line 
    var cast = (IEventHandler<IEvent>)handler;
```

But I got exception when I want to cast instance.

> Unable to cast object of type
> 'TestProject.ClientApi.PersonCreatedEventHandler' to type
> 'TestProject.ClientApi.IEventHandler`1[ElearnoInstitute.Endpoint.ClientApi.IEvent]'.

Why I get this exception? and how can resolve this problem.

Comment: Just because `PersonCreatedEventHandler` is `IEventHandler<PersonCreatedEvent>` it doesn't make `IEventHandler<PersonCreatedEvent>` an `IEventHandler<IEvent>`

Comment: I understand, but `PersonCreatedEvent` inherit from `IEvent` and I want to know, is there  way to cast to `IEventHandler<IEvent>`

Comment: Short answer: no. These types are simply not compatible. Take a moment to think about how you would (successfully) call `cast.Handle` -- you have stated you would like to be able to plug in any `IEvent`, but `PersonCreatedEventHandler` can only deal with `PersonCreatedEvent` instances.

Comment: Note that you can do something like `Func<IEvent, Task> x = evt => handler.Handle((PersonCreatedEvent) evt)` -- the resulting delegate is compatible with the signature of `IEventHandler.Handle`, and you could implement this as a class, but of course things will fail at runtime now if the passed in `IEvent` is not a `PersonCreatedEvent`. Somewhere, someone has to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That cast operation is forbidden because it can cause inconsistency problems. This is best explained with an example.

If we declare this class:

```
public class TestCreatedEvent : IEvent {

}
```

If your code were to be valid, we could do something like this:

```
var handler = new PersonCreatedEventHandler();
var cast = (IEventHandler<IEvent>)handler;
cast.Handle(new TestCreatedEvent());
```

We are passing an instance of something that's not a `PersonCreatedEvent` to the handler, that is a `IEventHandler<PersonCreatedEvent>` but not a `IEventHandler<TestCreatedEvent>`. The C# compiler gives the error to prevent that you can pass instances of another descendent type.

You can't cast types with generics to the same type but the generic being a super type. Another good example would be having a `List<B>`, `B` extending `A`, and having another class `C` also extending `A`. If you could cast `List<B>` to `List<A>`, you could add `C` instances to the casted `List<A>`, but originally that list is of type `List<B>`. Therefore, the result would be that you have `C` instances in a `List<B>`, which is a clear inconsistency.

Comment: For me it's always best explained with the [unsafe giraffes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase) sample. `IList<IGiraffe> giraffes = new List<IGiraffe>(); IList<IAnimal> animals = giraffes; animals.Add(new Lion());`. The assignment is not allowed for obvious reasons, just if `giraffes` was an array instead of a list, because you can't modify arrays.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that's also a good example. In Java, the behaviour is also the same with generics.