# C# list of classes that all inherit from common class

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

I have classes **A** & **B**. Both of them share some same parameters *x*, *y*, *z* inherited from abstract class **C**. Is it possible to make class **D** that contains List of objects that inherit from class **C**?

So I can do:

```
D d = new D();
d.list = new List<A>();
```

As well as:

```
D d = new D();
d.list = new List<B>();
```

**Edit:**
Objects in list have to be modifiable.
Following is more precisely described problem:

```
public abstract class C
    {
        // ...
    }

public class A : C
    {
        // ...
    }

public class D
    {
        public void Method(List<C> list)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

When I call:

```
List<A> list = new List<A>();
D d = new D();
D.Method(list);
```

I get „CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from A to C“.

Comment: `new List<C>()` maybe?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you want to do with this list?

Comment: In short - it is not possible. Fo reasons why - check out for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033921/2501279). Your edit does not add anything in terms of understanding what you are trying to do and why.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only readonly operations on the `list` you can declare it as a [covariant collection interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces) for example `IEnumerable` or `IReadOnlyList`:

```cs
IReadOnlyList<C> list = new List<A>();
list = new List<B>();
list = new List<C>();
```

Otherwise there is not much options besides making `D` a generic class (or using `List<C>` i.e. `List<C> list = new List<C>();`).