# C# DependencyProperty of generic class in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have read lots of questions and answers to solve this problem, but haven't found anything that helps with this problem. I am trying to expose a minimal example, so this is not exactly my real code (if there is any mistake in it, please, advice me).

What do I want to do? I am just trying to create a UserControl that uses a generic class. I want to use it like the WPF frameworks works, I mean, I want to be able to bind a property to a generic object of any class (`Itemssource` in the WPF framework case, you can bind it to `ObservableCollection<AnyClass>`).

First of all I define my class:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> where T : IMyItemInterface
{ 
    public ObservableCollection<T> MyOriginalList { get; set; }
    public T MySelectedItem { get; set; }
    ... more code here ...
}
```

Then I create a UserControl (`MyUserControl`) with this DependencyProperty in it:

```
public partial class MyUserControl: UserControl
{
... code here ...

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsListProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsList", typeof(MyGenericClass<IMyItemInterface>),
    typeof(MyUserControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsListChanged)));

private static void OnItemsListChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyUserControl myControl = (MyUserControl)d; // just for debugging
}

public MyGenericClass<IMyItemInterface> ItemsList
{
    get => (MyGenericClass<IMyItemInterface>)GetValue(ItemsListProperty); 
    set => SetValue(ItemsListProperty, value);
}

... more code here ...
}
```

This code compiles, but it does not work. If I set a breakpoint in `OnItemsListChanged`, it never fires.

I can change `typeof(MyGenericClass<IMyItemInterface>)` to `typeof(object)` this way:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsListProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsList", typeof(object),
    typeof(MyUserControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnListaItemsChanged)));
```

Now it does fire `OnItemsListChanged` but now I have a casting excepcion in `get => (MyGenericClass<IMyItemInterface>)GetValue(ItemsListProperty);`, and it is logical because MyGenericClass derives from object and not object from MyGenericClass. So I have also tried to change the property to:

```
public object ItemsList
{
    get => GetValue(ItemsListProperty); 
    set => SetValue(ItemsListProperty, value);
}
```

Now it compiles again and remains firing `OnItemsListChanged` but now I cannot use ItemList for anything because I cannot refer to `ItemLists.MySelectedItem` (for example), because `MySelectedItem` does not exist in `object` class.

The question is: what is the right approach for it? what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

What I bind to `ItemsList` is an instance of MyGenericClass. For example, I have a class that implements IMyItemInterface (`MyClassItem`), and after doing in code-behind `MyGenericClass<MyClassItem> myItem = new();`, I bind in XAML this way:

```
<MyCustomControl ItemsList={Binding myItem, Mode=TwoWay} />
```

Comment: Is MyGenericClass supposed to be an IEnumerable or ICollection or IList? Than use IEnumerable/ICollection/IList as the type of the dependency property. Also clarify why your UserControl should implement INotifyPropertyChanged. That's pointless for dependency properties.

Comment: @Clemens you are right, INotifyPropertyChanged is pointless for dependency properties, I edit not the question and remove it. About the other question, no, it is not an IEnumerable, but it has properties inside which are IEnumerable. I update the question. Thank you

Comment: Any binding errors in the Output window?

Comment: @Carlos: What do you set or bind your `ItemsList` property to?

Comment: @mm8 I have updated the question with this information. Thank you

Comment: Why is there `Mode=TwoWay` on the ItemsList Binding? Does MyCustomControl set the value of its ItemsList property - which is something different than modifying the properties of the MyGenericClass instance?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Yes: System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property. MyGenericClass`1:'MyGenericClass`1[MyClassItem]' BindingExpression:Path=myItem; DataItem='MyViewModel' (HashCode=30427456); target element is 'MyCustomControl' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsList' (type 'MyGenericClass`1')
MyGenericClass

Comment: @Clemens I set Mode=TwoWay because I would like to update some properties of `MyGenericClass` from the UserControl. But maybe it is not important for my problem, maybe you can ignore Mode=TwoWay, because my real problem is the binding and the cast of the interface. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be sufficient to declare the dependency property type like this:

```
public class MyItemsList
{
    public ObservableCollection<IMyItemInterface> MyOriginalList { get; set; }
    public IMyItemInterface MySelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

and the dependency property like this:

```
public MyItemsList ItemsList
{
    get { return (MyItemsList)GetValue(ItemsListProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsListProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsListProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ItemsList), typeof(MyItemsList), typeof(MyUserControl));
```

Assignments like these (and equivalent Bindings) would now work:

```
c.ItemsList = new MyItemsList { MySelectedItem = new MyClassItem() };
```

Comment: Yes, this would be one possible solution, but this is not a generic class. I need it to be generic, `MyGenericCollection<T>` (or `MyItemsList<T>` as you named it), with generics is where my problem appears. I would like to be able to bind an object of `MyGenericCollection<MyClassItem>` or and object of  `MyGenericCollection<MyClassItem2>` to MyUserControl, the same way I bind `MyGenericCollection<MyClassItem>` and `MyGenericCollection<MyClassItem2>` to ItemsSource of an ObservableCollection without any problem.  Thank you

Comment: But you should have understood that that won't work. "*I need it to be generic*" is only true as long as you don't think about alternatives.

Comment: Sure, but I am still missing something. Sorry.

Comment: You are absolutetly right. I have finally understood it. Thank you

Comment: Maybe this link is useful for someone with the same problem: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/a-best-practice-for-designing-interfaces-in-net-c-2c6ebdb4f1c1

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a property of type `MyGenericClass<IMyItemInterface>` to an `MyGenericClass<MyClassItem>` because a `MyGenericClass<MyClassItem>` is *not* a `MyGenericClass<IMyItemInterface>` just because `MyClassItem` implements `IMyItemInterface`.

This is called variance and C# restricts variant type parameters to generic interfaces and generic delegate types.

For example, you can set an `IEnumerable<object>` field to a `List<string>` but you cannot set a `List<object>` field to a `List<string>` despite the fact that `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

That's your issue and why your dependency property isn't set and your callback isn't invoked.

Please refer to this question and answers for more information:

[C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase)

The [docs on covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) should also be helpful.

Comment: After reading your answer, I have come to the conclusion I have to study more (a lot more)... Thank you. But now I have one (maybe stupid) question... would it help if `MyGenericClass` implemented IEnumerable<T> interface? As it is a covariant interface, would it help with the casting? Thank you