# C#, How to pass a List of a Derived class to a method that receives a List of the Base class?

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, covariance

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public abstract class FruitBox<T>
{
    public T item;

    public static T ChooseFirst(List<FruitBox<T>> fruitBoxes)
    {
        return fruitBoxes[0].item;
    }
}

public class Apple
{
}

public class AppleBox : FruitBox<Apple>
{
}

public class FruitShop
{
    List<AppleBox> appleBoxes = new List<AppleBox>();

    public void Main()
    {
        AppleBox appleBox = new AppleBox();
        appleBoxes.Add(appleBox);

        AppleBox.ChooseFirst(appleBoxes); // => Error here
    }
}
```

I have an error in the line:

```
AppleBox.ChooseFirst(appleBoxes);
```

> cannot convert from `System.Collections.Generic.List<AppleBox>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<FruitBox<Apple>>`

I tried:

```
AppleBox.ChooseFirst((List<FruitBox<Apple>>)appleBoxes);
```

But same error.

How do I have to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for such behaviour is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase). In short - classes do not support [variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) in C# and `List<AppleBox>` is not `List<FruitBox<Apple>>`.

What you can do:

- "convert" collection (actually create a new one):

with `OfType<>().ToList()`

```cs
AppleBox.ChooseFirst(appleBoxes.OfType<FruitBox<Apple>>().ToList())
```

or just `ToList`

```cs
AppleBox.ChooseFirst(appleBoxes.ToList<FruitBox<Apple>>())
```

- change `ChooseFirst` signature to work with covariant [`IEnumerable<out T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-6.0) interface:

```cs
public abstract class FruitBox<T>
{
    public T item;

    public static T ChooseFirst(IEnumerable<FruitBox<T>> fruitBoxes)
    {
        return fruitBoxes.First().item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to hold the reference of the derived class into the base class variable

```
List<FruitBox<Apple>> appleBoxes = new List<AppleBox>();

FruitBox<Apple> appleBox = new AppleBox();
appleBoxes.Add(appleBox);

appleBox.ChooseFirst(appleBoxes);
```

Comment: This has the same problem as OP. `List<FruitBox<Apple>> appleBoxes1 = new List<AppleBox>()` will not compile cause `List<AppleBox>` is not `List<FruitBox<Apple>>`.