# Inheritance of type of observable collection

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, observablecollection

I have the following classes.

**Car.cs**

```
public class Car 
    {
   
   }
```

**scoda.cs**

```
public class scoda : Car
    {
   
    }
```

**Test.cs**

```
 public class Test
    {
       public ObservableCollection<scoda> scodaList;
        public Test()
        {
            scodaList = new ObservableCollection<scoda>();
            scoda s = new scoda();
            scodaList.Add(s);
            set(scodaList);
        }

        public void set(ObservableCollection<Car> list)
        {

        }
    }
```

I got the casting error when calling set method as below

Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<KillCarMain.deneme.scoda>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<KillCardMain.deneme.Car>'

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: A list of Scodas is not a list of cars. Think about what would happen if you add a Ford to the list from within the set method. For further informataion, look up "covariance".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, a collection of `Car` is not a collection of `Scoda`.
So you should convert your collection of `Scoda` into a collection of `Car`:

```
var carList = new ObservableCollection<Car>(scodaList.Select(s => (Car)s));
set(carList);
```

If you don't want to create a new `ObservableCollection`, you could define scodaList as a collection of `Car` objects:

```
public ObservableCollection<Car> scodaList;

private void test() 
{
    scodaList = new ObservableCollection<Car>();
    scoda s = new scoda();
    scodaList.Add(s);
    set(scodaList);
}
public void set(ObservableCollection<Car> list)
{

}
```

Comment: In this solution new instance of Observable collection is creted. How to send observable collection to the method by reference ? I want to keep observable collection reference in the set method.

Comment: @şahin I edited the answer. I hope it helps.