# Problem with generic interfaces and inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have this definition of an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Game<T> : IGame<T> where T : IGameItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    protected List<T> GameItems { get; set; } = new();

    public IReadOnlyList<T> Items => GameItems.AsReadOnly();

    public void AddGameItem(T gameItem)
    {
        if(gameItem is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(gameItem));
        }
        this.GameItems.Add(gameItem);
    }

    public void RemoveGameItem(T gameItem)
    {
        if (gameItem is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(gameItem));
        }

        this.GameItems.Remove(gameItem);
    }
}
```

where ***IGame*** is (***IItem*** only contains a property Id of type Guid):

```
public interface IGame<T> : IItem where T : IGameItem
{
    IReadOnlyList<T> Items { get; }

    void AddGameItem(T gameItem);

    void RemoveGameItem(T gameItem);
}
```

where ***IGameItem*** is inherits from *IItem* but it´s empty for the moment.

Then I have the definition of ***IWordGame*** which is:

```
public interface IWordGame : IGame<IWordGameItem>
{
   *** Some properties here ***
}
```

And ***IWordGameItem*** inherits from ***IGameItem*** and adds some other properties.

The problem comes when I create a class that derives from Game

```
public class WordGame : Game<WordGameItem>, IWordGame
{
}
```

The class keeps complaining that I haven´t implemented the properties and methods of the IGame interface... But those methods are implemented in the Game base class... What am I missing? Do I need to restructure the arquitecture? What´s the best way to do it? If I implement the methods this is how the code goes:

```
IReadOnlyList<IWordGameItem> IGame<IWordGameItem>.Items => throw new NotImplementedException();

public void AddGameItem(IWordGameItem gameItem)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void RemoveGameItem(IWordGameItem gameItem)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

However I don´t want to implement the methods there but in the base class. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `WordGame` to:

```cs
public class WordGame : Game<IWordGameItem>, IWordGame
{
}
```

The thing is that `Game<WordGameItem>` is not `IGame<IWordGameItem>` (imagine that it would me true, then with `class WordGameItem1 : IWordGameItem` you would be able to call `Game<WordGameItem>.AddGameItem(new WordGameItem1())` which obviously is not type safe, this is explained in more detail for example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033921/2501279)).

Comment: Wow... it works but I don´t fully understand why. I though that I understood Covariance and Contravariance in generics but seems like I don´t. Thanks for sharing a link to another answer.

Comment: @Jaime Was glad to help! There is no variance involved here. There is no variance for classes (hence `Game`) in C# and the `IGame` interface is invariant. So this works because `IWordGame` requires `IGame<IWordGameItem>` to be implemented and `Game<IWordGameItem>` as per definition implements it (i.e. simple generic type construction with `T` -> `IWordGameItem`).

Comment: Ohhh now I get it... thank you very much. Very good explanation!

Comment: In other words, the definition in your question was trying to extend a class that implements `IGame<WordGameItem>` and implement `IWordGame : IGame<IWordGameItem>`, which you didn't do.