# How to sort a generic class?

Tags: c#, sorting, generics

How can I sort a list of this class where T in the list can be string and integers.

Edit: I have simplified the query code. The ToArray() method in results2 generates the error. Why is that?

```
var results1 = Entities.OrderBy(x => ((Cell<object>)x.RowData[CurrentPlugin.SortOrderInfo.ColumnIndex]).Value);
var results2 = Entities.OrderBy(x => ((Cell<object>)x.RowData[CurrentPlugin.SortOrderInfo.ColumnIndex]).Value).ToArray();
```

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Cell`1[System.String]' to type 'Cell`1[System.Object]'.'

```
public class Cell<T> : IComparable<Cell<T>>
{
    public Cell()
    {
        Text = string.Empty;
        Value = default;
    }
    public Cell(int index)
    {
        Index = index;
        Text = string.Empty;
        Value = default;
    }
    public Cell(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
        Value = default;
    }
    public Cell(string text, T value)
    {
        Text = text;
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Cell<T>? other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return 1;

        // Compare based on the type of the values
        if (Value is IComparable<T> comparableValue)
            return comparableValue.CompareTo(other.Value);

        // If the Value type is not comparable, just compare the Text values
        return Text.CompareTo(other.Text);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: How can I sort a list of this class where T in the list can be string and integers.

Comment: `List<Cell<int>> list = ...`, `list.Sort()`. Or `var sorted = list.Order().ToList()` (`list.OrderBy(x => x).ToList()` for older frameworks)

Comment: The list contains Cell<int> and Cell<string>.

Comment: @AmirRezaei you are answering to me? `List<Cell<int>> list` is a list containing `Cell<int>`.

Comment: If you are talking about `List<object>`  (or `List<Cell<object>>`)- then try avoid doing that. Also there is no "natural" comparison between string and integer, you will need to write custom comparer implementing such logic and pass it to `Sort` or `Order`.

Comment: In short -  provide a [mre] with some sample inputs and desired outputs. Currently it is not clear what you are trying to do and what the actual problem is.

Comment: What is difference between `new Cell<int>(string.Empty)` and `new Cell<int>(string.Empty, 0)` ? In my opinion the class is bad designed. You should be more based on `T` parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code:

```
.ThenBy(x => ((Cell<object>)x.RowData[CurrentPlugin.SortOrderInfo.ColumnIndex]).Value))
```

Will not work because `Cell<T>` is not `Cell<object>` unless `T` == `object` (for example - [C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2033912/2501279) ). Even if you will introduce covariant `interface ICell<out T>` it still will not work for `int`'s because [variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) is supported only for reference types.

Workarounds:

1. Compare against actual type:

   If you know that list can contain both ints and strings then you can do something like:

   ```cs
   x.OrderBy(o => o switch
        {
            Cell<int> ints => ints.Value.ToString(),
            Cell<string> strings => strings.Value,
            _ => null
        })
        .ToList();
   ```

   If you know that data is homogeneous then you can go with boxing approach:

   ```cs
   x.OrderBy(o => o switch
        {
            Cell<int> ints => (object)ints.Value,
            Cell<string> strings => strings.Value,
            _ => null
        })
        .ToList();
   ```
2. Implement non-generic `IComparable` (not sure how though) and cast to it.
3. In case of homogeneous you can create non-generic interface:

   ```cs
    interface ICell
    {
        public object Value { get; }
    }
   ```

   and implement it [explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) and cast to it.
4. Implement `IComparer<Entity>`:

   ```
   class StringOrIntCellComparer : IComparer<Entity>
   {
       public int Compare(Entity? left, Entity? right)
       {
           var x = left.RowData[CurrentPlugin.SortOrderInfo.ColumnIndex];
           var y = right.RowData[CurrentPlugin.SortOrderInfo.ColumnIndex];
           if (x is Cell<int> xi && y is Cell<int> yi)
           {
               return xi.Value.CompareTo(yi.Value); // or call compare from class
           }

           if (x is Cell<string> xs && y is Cell<string> ys)
           {
               return xs.Value.CompareTo(ys.Value); // or call compare from class
           }

           // todo: type mismatch or unsupported type
           throw new Exception();
       }
   }
   ```

   and use in in the `OrderBy` - `Entities.OrderBy(x => x, new StringOrIntCellComparer())`

But possibly you need to rework your design completely.

P.S.

> The ToArray() method in results2 generates the error

Because LINQ is lazy and `result1` does not actually perform filtering while `ToArray` is one of the materialization operators which results in actual execution.