# Set a generic class reference to a base class, where the generic class's generic parameter extends that base class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

I have a class AIBrain, and two other classes "StaffBrain" and "ClientBrain". The "StaffBrain" and "ClientBrain" classes both extend the "AIBrain" class.

```
public class AIBrain {
    public int Id;
}
```

```
public class StaffBrain : AIBrain {
    public int Salary;
}
```

```
public class ClientBrain : AIBrain {
    public int Spendings;
}
```

Now, I have another class "AIManager":

`public class AIManager<T> where T : AIBrain`

Now the issue is when I want to have a field "Manager" on the base class AIBrain. Inside a "AssignManager" method inside the AIManager class, I would like to be able to set an AIBrain's field "Manager" to the AIManager class. Like this:

```
public class AIBrain { // The class from earlier, just modified
    public int Id;
    public AIManager<AIBrain> Manager;
}
```

```
public class AIManager<T> where T : AIBrain { // The class from earlier, but with the "AssignManager" method
    public void AssignManager(T aI) {
        aI.Manager = this; // <- Throws error "Cannot implicitly convert type"
    }
}
```

However, when trying to do "aI.Manager = this", I get a compilation error: "Cannot implicitly convert type". I understand the reasoning behind this, but I can't find a proper solution to keep this as generic as possible, while also having fairly strong typing.

Does anybody have any suggestion on how I can achieve this?

DotNetFiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/AO5MIK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short - it is not possible in general case because in general case `AIManager<SomeInheritorOfAIBrain>` is not `AIManager<AIBrain>` - see [C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2033912/2501279) for more detailed explanation.

In some cases you can leverage C# support of [variance in generic interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces). For example in your surrogate example the following will work:

```cs
public interface IAIManager<out T> where T : AIBrain
{
}

public class AIBrain {
    public IAIManager<AIBrain> Manager;
}

public class AIManager<T> : IAIManager<T> where T : AIBrain {
    public void AssignManager(T aiBrain) {
        aiBrain.Manager = this;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/INv2gO)

But this is quite limited to what you can do with the `AIBrain.Manager` (and what you can declare in the interface).

Alternatively you can go with [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and make `AIBrain` generic:

```
public class AIBrain<T> where T:AIBrain<T> {
    public AIManager<T> Manager;
}

public class ClientBrain : AIBrain<ClientBrain> { }

public class StaffBrain : AIBrain<StaffBrain> { }

public class AIManager<T> where T : AIBrain<T> {
    public void AssignManager(T aiBrain) {
        aiBrain.Manager = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This indeed limits me because I am planning to include a method like "public void Delete(T aI)" - and I can't find a way to declare this in that interface. I am okay with going with a different solution though, if you have any suggestion of a fairly similar approach.