# Is C# element inside Tuple cannot be upcasted?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, tuples, upcasting

I'm encountering a compilation error in C# .NET 8.0 when trying to pass a `Dictionary` with a tuple as its key to a method. The tuple consists of a base class and another class, but when I try to use a derived class in place of the base class within the tuple, the code fails to compile. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
class A{};
class B : A {};
class X{};

void bar(Dictionary<(A sup, X oth), X> MyDicArg) {
    // Do something with Dictionary using that tuple
}

void foo() {
    var arg = new Dictionary<(B sup, X oth), X>();
    bar(arg); // Compilation error here
}
```

Since B is a subclass of A, I thought I could use a Dictionary with a key of (B, X) where a Dictionary with a key of (A, X) is expected due to implicit upcasting, but it does not seem to happening.

Could someone explain why this type mismatch occurs and how I might work around this issue? Is there a way to make the method accept a dictionary with a derived class in the tuple key, or do I need to adjust my approach?

Comment: Im not sure if C# support covariance with Tuples.
Depending on the dictionary size you could consider creating a new Dictionary before passing it to a function. Maybe you should have a look at the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: Only because `B` inherit `A`, doesn't make `Generic<B>` inherit `Generic<A>`(the same applies to dictionaries). See this question for the why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you are looking for is ***covariance*** (And its relative, ***contravariance***.)  Unfortunately, tuples in C# are neither covariant nor contravariant, because they are `struct`s, not `interface`s, and in C# only interfaces support covariance/contravariance.

In your specific example you should consider the limitation as just fine, because if this limitation was not there, you would be allowed to *potentially* shoot yourself in the foot.

This is because `foo()` has a dictionary of a more-derived class, and you wanted it to hand-out this dictionary to `bar()` which would treat it as containing a less-derived class, but you are using `Dictionary`, not `IReadOnlyDictionary`, so `bar()` is free to add a less-derived class into the dictionary, thus wreaking havoc into `foo()`.

Comment: oh, you were just 6 second faster :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having occurs due to the lack of covariance/contravariance support for tuple types in C#. To be more detailed:

Variance allows you to use a more derived type in place of a less derived type (covariance) or vice versa (contravariance)- unfortunately tuples don't act like this.

In your case B is derived from A, but (B, X) is not implicitly convertible to (A, X). This is because tuple types in C# do not automatically support covariance.

You could do a workaround and convert (B,X) to (A,X), for example:

```
void foo()
{
    var arg = new Dictionary<(B sup, X oth), X>();
    
    var convertedArg = arg.ToDictionary(entry => ((A)entry.Key.sup, entry.Key.oth), entry => entry.Value);

    bar(convertedArg);
}
```