My parameter of type DBset<CertainClass> is not receiving my DBset<SubclassOfThatCertainClass> object
When I try to put an object of a certain class into a parameter of a class it extends from, it tells me that it cannot be done.
I have a component called Grid.razor that is supposed to show a grid of a table and I wanted it to work on multiple tables and be reusable. That is why I created a class called FilaAMostrar for other tables to extend from. Now I have a parameter that accepts Dbset<FilaAMostrar> in my grid but when I put in my Dbset<PlanesCuentas> object in there it tells me it's not compatible.
This is the line of code that gives me trouble, specifically the SetDeDatos part:
<Grid TipoDeTabla="typeof(Models.PlanesCuentas)" _context="_context" SetDeDatos="_context.planes_cuentas"> </Grid>

Here is how I have them declared in the razor component:
private string? NotificacionMostrada = null;
[CascadingParameter]
public string? EmpresaSeleccionadaValida { get; set; }

[Parameter] 
public Type TipoDeTabla { get; set; }

[Parameter] 
public DataContext _context { get; set; }

[Parameter] 
public DbSet<FilaAMostrar> SetDeDatos { get; set; }

private string? AnteriorEmpresaSeleccionadaValida;

[CascadingParameter]
public Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

[Inject]
public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; set; }

private List<string> ColumnasDisponibles = new List<string>();
private List<string> ColumnasMostradas = new List<string>();
private List<Columna> Columnas { get; set; } = new List<Columna>();

private List<FilaAMostrar> FilasDeLaTabla = new List<FilaAMostrar>();
private List<FilaAMostrar> FilasDeLaTablaFiltradasPorEmpresaSeleccionadaValida = new List<FilaAMostrar>();
private ApplicationUser? signeduser = new ApplicationUser();

This is my PlanesCuentas class:
namespace BusinessERPWeb.Models
{
    public class PlanesCuentas : FilaAMostrar 
    {
        // Specific parameters of this class
    }
}

This is my FilaAMostrar class:
namespace BusinessERPWeb.Models
{
    public class FilaAMostrar
    {
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string? Codigo_de_Empresa { get; set; }

        public int Nivel { get; set; }
        public string? Padre {  get; set; }

        // Para cada clase que se extienda de esta clase hay que recordar desmapear estos atributos en el DataContext
        public bool Seleccionado { get; set; }
        public bool MostrarHijos { get; set; }
        public bool EsEditable { get; set; }
    }
}


While this severely lacks a [mre] the underlying issues is that while PlanesCuentas is  FilaAMostrar, the Dbset<PlanesCuentas> is not Dbset<FilaAMostrar>. Why exactly - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033921/2501279 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Depending on what you are doing possibly you can workaround by using generics.
