# Question about generic function parameter

Tags: c#

I'm just wondering why passing a `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>` into this function `test(ICollection<object> t)` will not work, why can't I pass it in like passing a `string` into `test2(object t)`?

Doesn't make much sense to me!

Comment: Please show more information(e.g. code) about your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557/in-c-why-cant-a-liststring-object-be-stored-in-a-listobject-variable

Comment: Please provide the full declaration of the type "List". Do you mean System.Collections.Generic.List<T>, System.Collections.ArrayList, System.Collections.SortedList, or is it a class you implemented yourself?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `ICollection` isn't an output only interface, it is not covariant.

Consider this code:

```
void test(ICollection<object> t)
{
    t.Add(new TextBox());
}

List<string> lst;
test(lst);
```

What is supposed to happen when `test` tries to stuff a `TextBox` into a `List<string>`?

The contract for `ICollection<object>` is that any `object` can be put in, and items coming out will always be of type `object`.  But `List<string>` only meets half that contract.

Comment: Yes, it was more comprehensive than my answer would have been.

Answer (score 1):

Because in C# 3.0 and .NET 3.5 or prior `List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`. That means that the generic type of both List and  ICollection must be the same.
In this scenario `List<sting>` cannot be assigned to `List<object>` although string is derived from object. In the same way `List<string>` cannot be assigned to `ICollection<object>`.

In C# 4.0 and .NET 4.0 we have the concept of covariance and contra-variance that allow you to assign a `List<string>` to a `IEnumerable<object>`.

here is a piece of code that works in C# 4.0

```
public static void Test(IEnumerable<object> input) {
    // do something
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    var input = new List<string>();
    Test(input);
}
```

Comment: WRT to the last sentence: no they don't.  `ICollection<T>` is (correctly) invariant even in .NET versions that support generic variance (which actually includes .NET 3.5 as well as 4.0).

Answer (score 0):

Method `test()` expects the parameter value to be of a type that implements the interface `ICollection<object>`. Make sure class `List` does.

Answer (score 0):

@Ben's explanation is great and yes @Gallahad suggested, there are useful covariant and contravariant interfaces implemented in .Net 4.0. These allow you to do something like what you were trying to do, and guarantee that the pitfall code in Ben's example can't be written with them.

Meanwhile, you can of course do something like

```
private static void PrintAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
     foreach (var item in list)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
     }
}

static void Main()
{
     List<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
     PrintAll(numbers);
}
```

this is a good way to achieve covariance. Furthermore, you can restrict what PrintAll's generic argument to a convenient base class using where clause.