# covariance in c#

Tags: c#, casting, covariance

Is it possible to cast a `List<Subclass>` to `List<Superclass>` in C# 4.0?

Something along these lines:

```
class joe : human {}

List<joe> joes = GetJoes();

List<human> humanJoes = joes;
```

Isn't this what covariance is for?

if you can do:

```
human h = joe1 as human;
```

why shouldn't you be able to do

```
List<human> humans = joes as List<human>;
```

than it wouldn't be legal to do (joe)humans[0] because that item has been down casted.. and everyone would be happy. Now the only alternative is to create a new List

Comment: This is basically the same as [In C#, why can't a List<string> object be stored in a List<object> variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557/in-c-why-cant-a-liststring-object-be-stored-in-a-listobject-variable).

Comment: because `humans` would then be referring to an instance of `List<joe>`, which would cause problems as illustrated in @Jon's example.

Comment: yep, after he corrected the example i got it.. makes sense

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't do this, because it wouldn't be safe. Consider:

```
List<Joe> joes = GetJoes();    
List<Human> humanJoes = joes;
humanJoes.Clear();
humanJoes.Add(new Fred());
Joe joe = joes[0];
```

Clearly the last line (if not an earlier one) *has* to fail - as a `Fred` isn't a `Joe`. The invariance of `List<T>` prevents this mistake at *compile* time instead of execution time.

Comment: well humanJoes is a list of Human, so you shouldn't be attempting (or able) to extra a Joe from it. but each joe is a human, so it should be safe to cast all to subclass safely.

Comment: you certainly can do Human h = joesList[0] as Human.. and that's what i was looking for / asking about.. accept on a whole list level

Comment: @Sonic: Why wouldn't you be add an extra `Joe` or `Fred` to it? *That* sort of variance is *always* acceptable. Try it: `List<object> list = new List<object>(); list.Add("this is a string)";`. Why would you expect that to fail?

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `Joe joe = joes[0];`?

Comment: just pointing out that your example should not compile, but that should not prevent the ability to downcast a list. if you can do Human h = joe as Human. Why can't you do List<Human> h = List<Joes> as List<human>

Comment: @Sonic: Doh - my last line was wrong. Now it would compile, if the second line were valid - and it would have to fail at execution time. Both `joes` and `humanJoes` would refer to the same list... but `joes` is meant to be a list which *only* has `Joe` elements (or subclasses).

Comment: @Ian: Yes, it should. Kinda messed up the example - hopefully Sonic will still take another look and see the point though :)

Comment: oh.. i see what you did there :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I don't understand the design decision to make this fail at compile-time. If I do `Human person = new Fred();` and `Joe person2 = (Joe) person;` I will get a run-time error. If I can add a `Joe` instance to a `List<Human>`, why can't `List<Joe>` be widened to `List<Human>`? It seems like the CLR should allow line 2 and just throw an `InvalidCastException` on line 5, if only for consistency with the type system.

Comment: @robjb: Other than array covariance, the type system ensures that type failures only come through deliberate actions (such as the cast in your example). A cast indicates to the compiler, "I know you can't prove this is okay, but I believe it is. Please check at execution time." The last line *should* be safe - if you've genuinely got a `List<Joe>`, that should only contain `Joe` values. You shouldn't need to worry about every single statement in your code for type safety.

Answer (score 6):

Instantiate a new human-list that takes the joes as input:

```
List<human> humanJoes = new List<human>(joes);
```

Answer (score 2):

No.  The co/contravariance features of C# 4.0 only support interfaces and delegates.  The do not support concrete types like `List<T>`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-4-0

Comment: so i'd need to loop through and create a new object for each joe as human and add to new list? that's the only option?

Comment: It's not possible with `IList<T>`, because that's invariant.

Comment: @Jon doh. Didn't think that one through

Answer (score 1):

No. As Jared said, the co/contravariance features of C# 4.0 only support interfaces and delegates. However it doesn't work with `IList<T>` either, and the reason is that `IList<T>` contains methods to add and change items in the list -- as Jon Skeet's new answer says.

The only way to be able to cast a list of "joe" to "human" is if the interface is purely read-only by design, something like this:

```
public interface IListReader<out T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    T this[int index] { get; }
    int Count { get; }
}
```

Even a `Contains(T item)` method would not be allowed, because when you cast `IListReader<joe>` to `IListReader<human>`, there is no `Contains(human item)` method in `IListReader<joe>`.

You could "force" a cast from `IList<joe>` to `IListReader<joe>`, `IListReader<human>` or even `IList<human>` using a [GoInterface](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/gointerfaces.aspx). But if the list is small enough to copy, a simpler solution is to just copy it into a new `List<human>`, as Paw pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

If I allow your `List<Joe> joes` to be generalized as ...

```
  List<Human> humans = joes;
```

**... the two references `humans` and `joes` are, now onward, pointing to the exact same list.** The code following the above assignment has no way of preventing an insertion/addition of an instance of another type of human , say a Plumber, into the list. Given that `class Plumber: Human {}`

```
humans.Add(new Plumber()); // Add() now accepts any Human not just a Joe
```

the list that `humans` refers to now contains both joes and plumbers. Note that the same list object is still referred to by the reference `joes`. **Now if I use the reference `joes` to read from the list object I might pop out a plumber instead of a joe**. Plumber and Joe are not known to be implicitly interconvertable... so my getting of a plumber instead of a joe from the list  breaks down  type safety.  A plumber is certainly not welcome through a reference to a list of joes.

However in the recent versions of C# , its kind of possible to work around this limitation for a generic class/collection by  implementing a generic  interface whose type parameter has an `out` modifier on it.  Say   we  now have `ABag<T> : ICovariable<out T>`. The out modifier restricts the T to ouput positions only (e.g. method return types). You cannot enter any T into the bag. You can only read them out of it. **This allows us to generalize joes to an `ICovariable<Human>` without worrying about inserting a Plumber into it as the interface doesnt allow that.** We can now write ...

```
ICovariable<Human> humans = joes ; // now its good !
humans.Add(new Plumber()); // error
```