# Casting a generic class without specific type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

I have the following generic class

```
public class Home<T> where T : Class
{
   public string GetClassType
   {
       get{ return T.ToString() }
   }
}
```

Now, I'm getting an Object X which I know for sure is Home:

```
public void DoSomething(object x)
{
    if(x is // Check if Home<>)
    {
        // I want to invoke GetClassType method of x  
        // but I don't know his generic type
        x as Home<?> // What should I use here?
    }
}
```

Can I even make a cast without specifying the generic type of the class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're sure the argument to `DoSomething` will be a `Home<T>`, why not make it a generic method?

```
public void DoSomething<T>(Home<T> home)
{
   ...
}
```

Of course, it would be even easier if `DoSomething` should logically be an instance method on `Home<T>`.

If you *really* want to stick with what you have, you could use reflection (untested):

```
public void DoSomething(object x)
{
    // null checks here.

    Type t = x.GetType();

    if (t.IsGenericType &&
          && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Home<>))
    {
        string result = (string) t.GetProperty("GetClassType")
                                  .GetValue(x, null);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    else 
    {
        ... // do nothing / throw etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

What if Home derived from a base class?

```
public class Home
{
    public virtual string GetClassType { get; }
}
public class Home<T> : Home
    where T : class
{
    public override string GetClassType
    {
        get{ return T.ToString() } 
    }
    ...
}
```

and then

```
public void DoSomething(object x)
{
    if(x is Home)
    {
        string ct = ((Home)x).GetClassType;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! I had a generic class with 2 peroperties: `SomeClass Query` and `List<T> Items`. I didn't care about the `Items`, only needed the `Query`, so moving that to a base class fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but all answers posted so far have not directly addressed this question and instead only suggested workarounds (i.e. "use reflection", "make your `DoSomething()` method generic" or "create a non-generic base class and call this base class' method").

> Can I even make a cast without specifying the generic type of the class?

**So to clearly answer your question:** No it is not possible. Due to the [covariance constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) in C# you cannot cast into a generic class.

In more detail: I am assuming you would want to use `x as Home<object>` as the lowest common denomitator in order to be be able to call `toString()` provided by the `Object` class. Casting your `object x` to `Home<object>` would require covariance which is not possible with classes (only generic interfaces and delegates can be covariant). while this is great to [prevent mistakes at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4038168/2477619), it is certainly an annoyance when wanting to access methods on generic classes, as in your case. @n8wrl answer is probably your best shot in terms of "casting".

That being said, you could also go for an interface-based solution, using the [out flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) on your T parameter:

```
interface IHome<out T> {
  string GetClassType { get; }
}

public class Home<T> : IHome<T> where T : class
{
  public string GetClassType
  {
      get { return typeof(T).Name; }
  }
}
```

Then this should work:

```
public void DoSomething(object x)
{
    if(x is // Check if Home<>)
    {
        var y = x as IHome<object>;
        var z = y.GetClassType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about making the function generic?

```
public void DoSomething<T>(object x)
{
    if(x is Home<T>)
    {
        x as Home<T> ...
    }
}
```

Edit:
Another possiblity would be to create an interface which holds the property `GetClassName` so you would only need to check if it is of that interface.

```
public interface IDescribeClass
{
    public string GetClassName { get; set; }
}
```

BTW: I would use the full qualified name

```
public string ClassType
{
    get{ return typeof(T).FullName; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your method definition to something like this?

```
public void DoSomething<T>(Home<T> x)
{

}
```