# Converting a nested dictionary to IReadOnlyDictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, .net-4.5, readonly

I am trying to give out a `IReadOnly`-references to internal `Collection` objects.
This works well in most cases, but does not if i want to convert a dictionary containing a collection into an `IReadOnlyDictionary` containing a `IReadOnlyCollection`.

Here a code example:

```
    var list = new List<int>();
    IReadOnlyList<int> listReference = list; //works;

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    IReadOnlyDictionary<int, int> dictionaryReference = dictionary; //works

    var nestedList = new List<List<int>>();
    IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<int>> nestedReadOnlyListReference = nestedList; //works

    var nestedDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
    //IReadOnlyDictionary<int, IReadOnlyList<int>> nestedReadOnlyDictionaryReference = nestedDictionary; //does not work, can not implicitly convert

    //current workaround
    var nestedDictionaryReferenceHelper = new Dictionary<int, IReadOnlyList<int>>();
    foreach (var kvpNestedDictionary in nestedDictionary)
    {
        nestedDictionaryReferenceHelper.Add(kvpNestedDictionary.Key, (IReadOnlyList<int>)kvpNestedDictionary.Value);
    }
    IReadOnlyDictionary<int, IReadOnlyList<int>> nestedReadOnlyDictionaryReference = nestedDictionaryReferenceHelper; //works, but is only a reference to the internal List, not to the dictionary itself
```

The workaround is pretty ugly as it needs additional memory and needs manual updating every time the values of `nestedDictionary` change.

Is there any simple way to convert such nested dictionaries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[In this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567206/why-cant-i-cast-a-dictionary-of-one-value-type-to-dictionary-of-another-value-t) you can find a very good explanation why casting dictionary values is not supported. Please see the accepted answer of Eric Lippert.

Although *i would not recommend* this, you *could* use the following LINQ expression to cast the values of the dictionary to a read only list:

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<int, IReadOnlyList<int>> nestedReadOnlyDictionaryReference = nestedDictionary.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value as IReadOnlyList<int>);
```

It is a shorter version of your workaround and it is lazy evaluated, but i would not recommend this due to the following reasons:

1. This solution still creates a copy of the dictionary and does not update any new/deleted entries from the original dictionary.
2. The values of the dictionary, i.e. the readonly lists, refer to the original lists and changes there are updated in the read only versions in the dictionary too.

**This is inconsistent behavior and therefore a bad practice!**

Unless it is not possible to cast the values of a dictionary, i would not recommend doing this. You should either deep copy the entire dictionary including the nested lists, or use an other container that supports casting.

Comment: I edited the answer to provide a better description why the solution using LINQ is bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the point is the you're missing the opportunity to introduce a proper **new type** with its own dignity. If you're using `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` then you will see yourself with code like this every time you need to insert a value:

```
if (!_dictionary.ContainsKey(key)) {
    var list = new List<int>();
    list.Add(value);
    _dictionary.Add(key, list);
} else {
    _dictionary[key].Add(value);
}
```

And even worse with code like this when you want to search for a value:

```
_dictionary.ContainsKey(key) && _dictionary[key].Contains(value);
```

And variation of those examples. What's worse you're exposing this **implementation detail** to your class users. If this detail will change then you will break all code. What, for example, if you want to replace `List<int>` with `HashSet<int>`?

---

How it should be?

```
_multimap.Add(key, value);
```

With a proper interface (here I show just few methods):

```
public interface IMultiMap<TKey, TValue> {
    void Add(TKey key, TValue value);
    bool ContainsKey(TKey key);
}
```

And its implementation:

```
public sealed class MultiMap<TKey, TValue> : IMultiMap<TKey, TValue> {
    // ...

    private Dictionary<int, List<int>> _items;
}
```

You can introduce `IReadOnlyMultiMap<TKey, TValue>`:

```
public interface IReadOnlyMultiMap<TKey, TValue> {
    bool ContainsKey(TKey key);
}
```

Just implement `IReadOnlyMultiMap<TKey, TValue>` in `MultiMap<TKey, TValue>` and to return a read-only collection you have nothing to do (fictional example):

```
IReadOnlyMultiMap<int, int> MakeReadOnly(MultiMap<int, int> map) {
    return map; // Nothing to do!
}
```

Note that you may want to introduce a new `ReadOnlyMultiMap<TKey, TValue>` to tunnel read calls to underlying live collection (to avoid callers to simply cast to `MultiMap<TKey, TValue>` to circumvent read-only limitation). Proof of concept:

```
public sealed class ReadOnlyMultiMap<TKey, TValue> : IReadOnlyMultiMap<TKey, TValue> {
    public ReadOnlyMultiMap(IMultiMap<TKey, TValue> collection) {
        _collection = collection;
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) {
        return _collection.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    private readonly IMultiMap<TKey, TValue> _collection;
}
```

To return a read-only view you do:

```
IReadOnlyMultiMap<int, int> MakeReadOnly(MultiMap<int, int> map) {
    return new ReadOnlyMultiMap<int, int>(map);
}
```

---

Note that I talked about *implementation detail*. You're still exposing an implementation detail (you're using a multimap) then if such code is for a public API you should introduce a new (properly named) type to describe **what it contains, not how storage is implemented**. It may be `MeasureCollection`, `SoccerScoreCollection` or whatever your model is talking about, storage may vary but *content* won't.

Comment: while i emphasize with your eagerness to discuss code design, this clearly is not helpful in this case. The provided code is an example, and your answer is lacking the explanation of the underlying problem (see answer of Philip)

Comment: ...which, however, doesn't provide any solution (because with that LINQ dictionary is _detached_, not _live_ as you requested). Answer (IMO, of course) to your problem then is to change your design (both from a philosophical POV and as practical solution). That said E.L. articles are always good references and I'm not here to discuss your downvote and your own opinion...

Comment: Philip's solution is not his workaround, it's the information about important C# limitations

Comment: It's pointless debate but: if your question was _"**why** I can't do this?"_ then I'd agree (and I'd vote to close this post as duplicate of the other one, BTW). However you were asking for a solution (which isn't just "you can't because of C#"). IMO, of course, I have to respect _your_ opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Problem for conversion failing is the KeyValuePair:
Although class Derived inheriting class Base, KeyValuePair is not a sub class of KeyValuePair; see definitions([Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [IReadOnlyDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136548%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

So you always will need some kind of workaround (MultiMap approach appears to me as one, too...). *If* `nestedDictionary` is private, so you have complete control over it from your class, you might get away with this:

```
var nestedDictionary = new Dictionary<int, IReadOnlyList<int>>();
IReadOnlyDictionary<int, IReadOnlyList<int>> nestedReadOnlyDictionaryReference = nestedDictionary;
```

and whenever modifying a list within the dictionary applying a cast to `List<int>`. Another ugly workaround, I admit, but saves you extra memory and redundancy management and retains the (asumed...) public interface of `IReadOnlyDictionary<int, IReadOnlyList<int>>`.

Edit: just an idea, haven't tested, but it *might* work: Have your own dictionary adding the missing interfaces to be assignable to the read-only dictionary:

```
public class MyDictionary
    : Dictionary<int, List<int>>,
      ICollection<KeyValuePair<int, IReadOnlyList<int>>,
      IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, IReadOnlyList<int>>, 
      IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<int, IReadOnlyList<int>>
{
}
```

I might yet have missed an interface to be implemented, and you *might* have to implement some members yet. If it works, possibly the cleanest solution...