# What Causes this System.InvalidCastException?

Tags: c#, casting, covariance

I see `System.InvalidCastException` when I tried the following:

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyCollection<MyType>> results = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentBag<MyType>>();
```

I do not understand the root cause for this error message:

> ConcurrentBag implements IReadOnlyCollection and ConcurrentDictionary implements IReadOnlyDictionary.

Why does the casting fail?

Comment: `ConcurrentBag<MyType>` implements `IReadOnlyCollection<MyType>`. `ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentBag<MyType>>` implements `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, ConcurrentBag<MyType>>`, but does not implement `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyCollection<MyType>>`.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966961/cannot-convert-from-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass) and [another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720751/casting-list-of-derived-class-to-list-of-base-class).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I cast a dictionary of one value type to dictionary of another value type when the value types can be cast from one another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567206/why-cant-i-cast-a-dictionary-of-one-value-type-to-dictionary-of-another-value-t)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyCollection<MyType>> results = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentBag<MyType>>();
```

You need to do this:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, IReadOnlyCollection<MyType>> results = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IReadOnlyCollection<MyType>>();
```

or

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentBag<Point>> results = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentBag<Point>>();
```

This is known as Covariance Limitation. Here is more read about it:
basically, if you have a container of parent, you can put any derived class in it. But if you have a container for child, then you can't put parent in it.

In Waterfall, water falls from top to bottom.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd799517(v=vs.100)