# Issue with casting List<ClassA> where ClassA:Generic<Int32> to List<Generic<Int32>>

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I have the next classes:

```
public class EntityBase<T>
{
    public T Id { get; set; }

}
```

And it's implementers:

```
public class ClassA : EntityBase<Int32>
{
     ...
}

public class ClassB : EntityBase<Int64>
{
     ...
}
```

And in the code, which dont know about classes - `ClassA` and `ClassB` it knows only about existance of the EntityBase<...>, I do something like this:

```
     // Here for sure I get the list of `ClassA`
     object obj = GetSomeHowListOfClassA();
     List<EntityBase<Int32>> listOfEntityBases = (List<EntityBase<Int32>>)obj;
```

And I get the error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[...ClassA]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[...EntityBase`1[System.Int32]]'.
```

I fix it like this:

```
var listOfEntityBases = new List<EntityBase<Int32>>(obj);
```

But I dont like this way, because I'm creating new List<>. Is there way to cast it? 
Thx for any advance.

Comment: try reading these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-sharp-4-0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038125/covariance-in-c-sharp etc

Comment: Problem is not in understanding of covariance and contravariance. But the problem is that List<> doesnt support contravariance. That's why I'm asking any workaround from this issue..

Comment: can you redesign it to use `MyClass<T> : EntityBase<T>` instead of `ClassA` and `ClassB`?

Comment: I dont think that it will fix the issue.

Comment: It may allow you to create generics methods - but it really depends on your design and usage. So you don't want new list creation (like this one `List<EntityBase<Int32>> listOfEntityBases = obj.Cast<EntityBase<Int32>>().ToList();`) - you are looking for pure cast?

Comment: yeap. I'm looking for pure cast. ) And also in this part of code I will do some modification and throw it to the other part of my programm in which I will cast it back to the (ClassA).

Comment: actually I am very confused why you would need to get an object. Have you considered a generic constraint `where T : EntityBase<TKey>`

Comment: You would not need to KNOW about `ClassA` as long as you have a generic argument which you place `ClassA` into AND you can still have your `List<ClassA>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do cast this way, because:

- covariance in C# isn't working for classes;
- interfaces `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>` aren't covariant.

The only option you can do here (except making a copy of a list) is a casting to `IEnumerabe<T>`:

```
var listOfEntityBases = (IEnumerable<EntityBase<Int32>>)obj;
```

Comment: I personally prefer `IEnumerable<EntityBase<Int32>> listOfEntityBases = obj`. The compiler will be forced to do an implicit (safe) cast, as opposed to an explicit (potentially unsafe) cast. Heuristically it is safe of course, but if we ever change `ClassA` then it could break at runtime.

Comment: @Aron: `IEnumerable<EntityBase<Int32>> listOfEntityBases = obj`- what? This even won't compile.

Comment: I mean `var obj = new List<ClassA>(); IEnumerable<EntityBase<Int32>> listOfEntityBases = obj;` for casting...

Comment: Ghm... As I wrote in my question - `And in the code, which dont know about classes - ClassA and ClassB it knows only about existance of the EntityBase<...>, I do something like this:`

Comment: @Aron: the question says, that `obj` has a `System.Object` type.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do it for clear reason. Let's assume this line of code **will** work:

```
 List<EntityBase<Int32>> listOfEntityBases = (List<EntityBase<Int32>>)obj;
```

This means that after that line you can do say following

```
listOfEntityBases.Add(new EntityBase<Int32>());
```

but actually this line in the same time will add `EntityBase<Int32>` object to your `obj` of type `List<ClassA>` - which is definitely **InvalidCast**.

So, you just cannot declare the **same** variable as `List<ClassA>` and `List<EntityBase<Int32>>` in the same time.

Though, it is easily allowed for `IEnumerable<T>` as you **can not** add new values for such collection.

And that's why they have `in` and `out` in generics declaration.

Comment: What Lanorkin is trying to describe is the difference between Covariance and Contravariance. An interface can't be both Covariant and Contravariant without being the same interface.

Comment: What I'm trying to describe is why it can not be casted. Differences clearely described in links I adviced to @Maris, while they still want to just cast.