# Cannot Convert Item to its interface exception

Tags: c#, exception, interface

I have the following class and interface:

```
public interface IFieldFiller
    {
        string Content { get; set; }
        Boolean Nullable { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
[DataContract]
public class FieldFiller : IFieldFiller
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Boolean Nullable { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public StoredProcedure StoredProcedure { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string NameSpace { get; set; }
}
```

I then use the following Linq statement to build a list of these objects:

```
Fields =  temp.merged_fields.Select(f => new FieldFiller { Name = f.name, NameSpace = f.@namespace, StoredProcedure = new StoredProcedure { Name = f.sproc1.name, Parameters = f.field_params.ToDictionary(p => p.sprocParam.name, p=>p.value)}}).ToList()
```

and I keep getting the following exception:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Services.Data.EmailTemplateAccess.Contracts.FieldFiller>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Services.Data.EmailTemplateAccess.Contracts.IFieldFiller>'
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error when FieldFiller implements IFieldFiller. I have already verified that they are in the correct namespaces. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `D : B`  does not imply `List<D> : List<B>`. You need to add the `D` elements to `List<B>` manually.

Comment: According to that blog, wouldn't FieldFiller be smaller than IFieldFiller, making it a covariant relationship that should be able to be rationalized by the compiler?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment once I re-read your problem. Covariance is only allowed on interfaces.  This is a very common problem: assuming that collections of some type have the same relationships as their contents.  Co-/contra- variance are solutions to them, but unnecessary for your needs, but still worth a read if you are interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FieldFiller` is also `IFieldFiller` but `List<FieldFiller>` is not a `List<IFieldFiller>`, you can cast it accordingly:

```
Fields =  temp.merged_fields
    .Select(f => (IFieldFiller)new FieldFiller { Name = f.name, NameSpace = f.@namespace, StoredProcedure = new StoredProcedure { Name = f.sproc1.name, Parameters = f.field_params.ToDictionary(p => p.sprocParam.name, p=>p.value)}})
    .ToList()
```

or, with .NET 4 you can use this(see: [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)):

```
...
    .Select(f => new FieldFiller { ... })
    .ToList<IFieldFiller>();
```

Why it's not safe:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4038168/284240 and
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8925442/284240