# Return derived class instance instead of base class instance

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I have an interface that looks like this

```
 public interface SomeInterface<T, U>
    where T : struct
    where U : class
{
    void Method1();
    IDictionary<T, BaseClassItem<U>> GetDictionary();
}
```

I have one of the implementations like this

```
public class LruEvictor<T, U> : SomeInterface<T, U>
    where T : struct
    where U : class
{
    private Dictionary<T, BaseClassItem<U>> _dictionary;

    public void Evict()
    {

    }
    public IDictionary<T, BaseClassItem<U>> GetDictionary()
    {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<T, BaseClassItem<U>>();
        return _dictionary;
    }

}
```

In the above GetDictionary() method I would like to return a dictionary of 
type `Dictionary<T, DerivedItem<U>>.`

Is that possible? If yes how do I do it.

Given below is the derived class implementation.

```
public class DerivedItem<U> : BaseClassItem<U>
    where U : class
{        

    public DerivedItem(U value) :base(value)
    {

    }
    public DateTime LastAccessed { get; private set; }

    public override void OnAccessed()
    {
        LastAccessed = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Any input will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [covariance in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038125/covariance-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you can't do this, as it would break the type system.

Consider the usual animal example:

```
public IDictionary<T, Animal> GetDictionary()
{
    _dictionary = new Dictionary<T, Llama>();
    return _dictionary; // Imagine you can do this
}

IDictionary<T, Animal> dict = GetDictionary();
dict.Add(MakeT(), new Horse()); // Ouch.
```

Comment: Thanks @ T.C. that make sense. i will accept this as answer since you replied first.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. A simple version of your question would be that given

```
class Base { }
class Derived : Base { }
```

is it possible to use `IDictionary<T, Base> dict = new Dictionary<T, Derived>()`.

This is not possible because covariance rules of C# don't allow that. And for good reason because if it would work then you could simply add an object of type `Base` to the dictionary that should only accept `Derived` objects.

Comment: Thanks @ Dirk. T.C and you helped me understand better. I have accepted T.C's answer since it came first.