# How can I implicitly convert List<Foo> to List<Bar> given that there's a cast operator defined?

Tags: c#, list, type-conversion

I have a type `Bar` that defines an implicit cast operator:

```
public static implicit operator Bar(Foo foo)
{
    return new Bar(foo.property);
}
```

Converting single objects works great, but now I have a `List<Foo>` and I need a `List<Bar>`.

I found this workaround:

```
List<Bar> barList = fooList.ConvertAll<Bar>(item => item);
```

which seems to do the trick, but it's somewhat defeating the point of an implicit cast operator if I have to apply it in this somewhat explicit sense. Is there any way to make the implicit conversion work for lists?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038125/covariance-in-c-sharp

Comment: You haven't shown the code where you're consuming the list, that can potentially change the approach to take. For example. if you consume it via a foreach then you don't need to convert the list: https://dotnetfiddle.net/p3b8Bb

Comment: @AndyJ I pass these lists around as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot make this cast implicit, although the reason is somewhat unexpected: when you explicitly provide a type argument to a generic method, C# requires you to provide all remaining arguments as well. It is this all-or-nothing approach that lets you write this

```
List<Bar> barList = fooList.Select(item => (Bar)item).ToList();
```

or this

```
List<Bar> barList = fooList.Select<Foo,Bar>(item => item);
```

but it does not let you write this:

```
List<Bar> barList = fooList.Select<...,Bar>(item => item);
//                                 ^^^
//                                  |
// Figure this out from the context |
```

Theoretically, C# *could* capture `Foo` from the type of `item`, but it does not have a feature to do it.

LINQ's `Cast<T>` is not going to work either, because it treats items being cast as plain `object`s, thus ignoring any conversion operators that may be defined on them.

Since you are required to specify both the "from" and the "to" types, a solution based on generics is not going to be any better than your solution based on `ConvertAll`.

Comment: Does `fooList.OfType<Bar>().ToList()` not work here or does it suffer from the same issue around how the casting happens?

Comment: @RobV `OfType<Bar>` would return an empty `IEnumerable<Bar>`: it applies the same logic as `Cast<Bar>`, but skips elements instead of throwing an exception when the cast is not possible.