# Generic Interface with array of generics

Tags: c#, generics

Assume we have following interface:

```
public interface ILine<T>
{
    T Item { get; set;}
}
```

I do have classes `Line1` and `Line2` implementing it

```
public class Item1
{
}

public class Item2
{
}

public class Line1 : ILine<Item1>
{
    public Item1 Item {get; set;}   
}

public class Line2 : ILine<Item2>
{
    public Item2 Item { get; set; }
}
```

Now i have a class

```
public class Lines1
{
    public Line1[] Items { get; set;}
}
```

I would like to create an interface

```
public interface ILines<T>
{
    ILine<T>[] Items { get; set;}
}
```

And let Lines1 implement it `Lines1 : ILines<Item1>`  (and `Lines2` do the same with `Item2`). But it's not possible, because of complier error

> 'Lines1' does not implement interface member 'ILines.Items'.
>   'Lines1.Items' cannot implement 'ILines.Items' because it does
>   not have the matching return type of 'IEnumerable>'.

The classes are deserialized from xml, so i really need properties as `Item1`, `Item2`, `Line1`, `Line2` not as interfaces. 
What could i do to go forward? Or i am trying to apply some famous antipattern?

**Update**: Very good explanation, why it is not possible: 
[covariance in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038125/covariance-in-c-sharp)

Unfortunately i haven't found it before writing question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ILine<T>[]` is not the same as `Line1[]`. There's plenty of answers on SO about the concept of *variance*, they can explain this clearly.

The solution is to make sure the types actually map to each other. One way to do this is to make `Line1` a generic argument as well:

```
interface ILines<T, U> where U : ILine<T>
{
  U[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

Sadly, this means you lose some of the type inferrence, so it can mean quite a bit of extra text.

Answer (score 0):

```
You may want to check this out.    

    public class LinesOne : ILines<Item1>
        {
            public ILine<Item1>[] Lines
            {
                get
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }

                set
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }
        }

        public class LinesTwo : ILines<Item2>
        {
            public ILine<Item2>[] Lines
            {
                get
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }

                set
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }
        }
        public interface ILines<T>
        {

            ILine<T>[] Lines { get; set; }
        }

        public interface ILine<T>
        {
            T Item { get; set; }
        }

        public class Item1
        {
        }

        public class Item2
        {
        }

        public class Line1 : ILine<Item1>
        {
            public Item1 Item { get; set; }
        }

        public class Line2 : ILine<Item2>
        {
            public Item2 Item { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: That is not what i want to achieve. You propose to use public ILine<Item1>[] Lines  and i need public Line1[] Items { get; set;} . Serializer, that creates objects, knows what Line1 class is, but couldn't create instances of an interface.